# xelatex error: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape

Tags: fonts, xetex, bold, small-caps

Thank you all in advance.
I know not much about fonts.
but once I compile my document I get:

```
    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 174.
```

I'm not sure how solve this issue, even though there are other similar posts here but the answers are all too advanced.

Comment: It's a warning. It tells you that there is no bold small caps font variant in your font family and that latex used the normal bold font instead. If the substituation is ok for you you can ignore the warning. If you badly need a bold small caps font you will have to change your font setup.

Comment: You can use bold caps from the `cm-super` pack. I recently used this hack for bold and slanted small caps with Latin Modern set as base font: http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/ixJe1C5F I'm pretty sure that there exists a more proper way to select `cmr` _only_ for `EU1/.../bx/sc`. I couldn't deal with the encoding, though, when I tried `\DeclareFontShape`.

Comment: Related question: [fonts - Small Caps and Bold Face - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face/346627#346627)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no "boldface small caps" font in the Latin Modern family, so LaTeX performs a substitution; in this case it preserves the "boldface" weight attribute and chooses the "normal" shape.

I don't think there's much to do in this case other than defining a different substitution, but medium weight small caps embedded in a boldface context is worse, I believe.

One can follow Andrey Vihrov's suggestion and write in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@scshape=\scshape
\renewcommand{\scshape}{%
  \ifnum\strcmp{\f@series}{bx}=\z@
    \usefont{T1}{cmr}{bx}{sc}%
  \else
    \ifnum\strcmp{\f@shape}{it}=\z@
      \fontshape{scsl}\selectfont
    \else
      \@@scshape
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

(I've slightly modified the code). However this uses a T1-encoded font, so only the characters in T1 are available.

If a "boldface small caps" font with a wide covering of Unicode is really needed, one should adopt a font family that has the required shape.

Comment: How can I check which Font it is that causing the issue so that I'll try to download the boldface small caps.

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie so Im not sure what a preamble or t1-encoded fonts are.

Comment: The preamble is the part of your document before `\begin{document}`; just add the "magic code" in front of it. A T1-encoded font covers approximately the Latin1 characters (suitable for most European languages).