# Choosing font for bold small caps (or any other particular family+series+shape combination)

Tags: fonts, best-practices, small-caps

What is the best way (most proper and general solution) to get rid of the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

by explicitly setting which font should be used for particular family+series+shape combination in edited document?

---

Bold small-caps are not widely available font-wise. E.g. they are available in CM-Super (which the default font for T1 encoding), but not in overall better Latin Modern.

Let's say I use Latin Modern as the default font (`\usepackage{lmodern}`). What should be done to make LaTeX fallback to CM-Super in case of bold small caps?
(And only in the case of bold small caps, medium small caps should remain typed using Latin Modern.)

Comment: As always a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as reference would be very much appreciated.  People could then use it to implement, test and compare their solutions.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22045/xelatex-error-latex-font-warning-font-shape or [\DeclareFontShape](http://ctan.org/pkg/fntguide) in general.

Comment: @Martin: I've avoided giving MWE on purpose. I prefer to make this a more general question, but I still gave a specific example w/ bold small caps and lmodern+cm-super, because sometimes people just prefer to think about concrete case.

Comment: Related question: [fonts - Small Caps and Bold Face - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face/346627#346627)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AFAIK you just need to declare that font shape using `\DeclareFontShape`. You can just declare the font shape to use the font shape of the standard font. This should lead to the same result as before just without the warning.

```
Using `lmodern` with `T1` font encoding you get the following warning with `\scshape\bfseries`:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 19.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

So you need to declare the font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc`. As Ulrike pointed out you can substitute another font using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} \normalfont %to load T1lmr.fd 
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc} { <-> ssub * cmr/bx/sc }{}

\begin{document}

{\normalfont normal font}
{\scshape small caps}
{\ttfamily tt family}
{\bfseries bold font}
{\scshape\bfseries bold small caps}% works and uses `cmr` font instead of `lmr`

\end{document}
```

Comment: Effort appreciated. It is good as it works for my exemplary case, but at the same time I cannot say I like it, because it requires checking and copying some stuff from `.fd` file, which I believe should be avoidable, as we're ultimately reusing family+series+shape already defined out there.

Comment: Mmm, Adobe Acrobat Reader crashes with the above MWE when I try to display Properties->Fonts! `pdffonts` actually displays the fonts nicely, so does `evince`.

Comment: Works in `okular` too, where I see shiny new `SFXC1200`. :-)

Comment: @przemoc: There's nothing else to do in this case; the font you desire is not available in the Latin Modern family. If their developers don't add themselves such a substitution, it's impossible for LaTeX to define it by itself: no default substitution can be allowed to change the family.

Comment: You can use the sub (or ssub) function to declare the substituation: `\usepackage{lmodern}` `\normalfont %to load T1lmr.fd`
`\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}
  { <-> ssub * cmr/bx/sc }{}`

Comment: @Ulrike: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and I believe this is the best solution. Could you "transform" your comment into separate answer? You can make it a bit more elaborate if you want. I will happily accept it after day or two. :-)

Comment: Martin can include it in his answer.

Comment: @Martin: Please include Ulrike's solution in your answer in some spare time. I wouldn't bother you, but I cannot do it myself yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Martin: One more thing -- your disclaimer is rather no longer relevant.

Comment: Can we apply this for `T1/lmr/n/n`?

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to use the technique from the previous comment, until I realised I was using a **sans** font and that the CM fonts **dont have** a 'sans serif' bold small caps...

To solve it, I used the helvet package which has them. There is an additional trick as you have to re-load the declaration for \sfdefault as \usepackage{helvet} overwrites it! Then it defaults to lmodern except for the sans small caps where you use helvet...

Just posting the code here in case it is useful to someone!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\sffamily %to load T1lmss.fd 

% Load 'sans small caps' from helvet:
\usepackage{helvet}
\sffamily %to load T1phvss.fd 
% Substitute non-existing lmss/bx/sc with phv/bx/sc
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmss}{bx}{sc} { <-> ssub * phv/bx/sc }{}
% Can also pick the sans small caps:
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmss}{m}{sc} { <-> ssub * phv/m/sc }{}

% Use lmodern to override helvet:
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}

\begin{document}

This is lmodern roman (lmr) -- default

{\sffamily This is lmodern sans (lmss)}

{\scshape This is small caps from lmodern (lmr)}

{\sffamily \scshape This is sans small caps from helvet (phv)}

{\sffamily \bfseries \scshape This is sans bold small caps from helvet (phv)}

\end{document}
```