# Writing bold small caps with mathpazo package

Tags: fonts, macros, bold, small-caps, mathpazo

The URW Palldio font (`mathpazo` package) does not provide bold small caps. To get round this issue, I'd want to make a macro to use small caps usually and normal caps in bold text.

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

% Use small caps normally except in a bold font: switch to uppercase instead.
% This macro does not work: the `\ifx\f@series\bfdefault` test always fails.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mytextsc}[1]{%
    \ifx\f@series\bfdefault%
        \uppercase{#1}%
    \else
         {\scshape #1}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% An other macro, where the same test is ok here !?
\newcommand\normal{\fontseries{\ifx\f@series\bfdefault\then m \fi}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
% this works OK
This is a \mytextsc{small caps} text.

% this fails
\textbf{This is a bold \mytextsc{upper case} text.}

% here the normal macro works
\textbf{This is a bold \mytextsc{upper \normal case} text.}
\end{document}
```

For some strange reason, the test `\ifx\f@series\bfdefault` always fails in the `\mytestsc` macro, although it works well in the `\normal` macro. Any ideas how to correct the `\mytextsc` macro?

Comment: Try putting `\makeatletter\show\f@series\show\bfdefault\makeatother` within the body of the `\textbf`.  What does Latex say?

Comment: this don't work, the latex file don't compile with `show` macro.

Comment: The `\show` command interrupts the compilation to show you the definition of commands, you must continue it by typing enter.

Answer (score 7):

### Update 2020

Due to changes in the latex kernel - series are now handled in a more sophisticated way - this will no longer work. It is now better to test against `\bfseries@rm` and `\bfseries@sf`. Perhaps there will be in future also be a generic test to check if one is in a "bold context".

I also suggest not to use \uppercase as it won't handle e.g. accents correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytextsc}{m}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF 
    {
      \tl_if_eq_p:NN \f@series \bfseries@rm
      ||
      \tl_if_eq_p:NN \f@series \bfseries@sf 
    }  
    {
      \text_uppercase:n{#1}%
    }
    {
      \textsc{#1}
    } 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff \makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a \textsc{small caps} \mytextsc{small caps} text.

\textbf{This is a bold \textsc{upper case} \mytextsc{upper text grüße} text.}

\sffamily
\textbf{This is a bold \textsc{upper case} \mytextsc{upper text grüße} text.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Old (outdated) answer.

`\bfdefault` is a long macro, `\f@series` not, so both are different and the test always gives false. This also happen in your "working" `normal` command which always gives `\fontseries{m}`. Expand the macros before the test:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mytextsc}[1]{%
 \edef\@tempa{\f@series}\edef\@tempb{\bfdefault}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \uppercase{#1}%
 \else
  {\scshape #1}%
 \fi }
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any bold small caps for mathpazo, according to [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24628/font-shape-undefined-with-latex-and-isodoc/24630#24630):

You should check the Latex warning to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to clarify my issue. It's not the missing font, but the macro.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `\bfdefault` isn't expanding correctly, but you can define a new macro that does what you want:

```
\makeatletter
\def\boldseriesname{bx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mytextsc}[1]{%
    \ifx\f@series\boldseriesname\uppercase{#1}%
    \else{\scshape #1}%
    \fi}
\makeatother
```