# Abbreviations for AM, PM (small caps) for use within \textbf

Tags: fontsize, bold, acronyms, small-caps

I have been using `\textsc` for the abbreviations for `AM`, `PM`, but it does not work within `\textbf{}`.  As you can see in the image, within a `\textbf{}`, it reverts to the normal lower case letter.  Ulrike Fischer suggests in [bold small caps with mathpazo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/4301), to switch to uppercase characters when attempting to use a bold weight font, but that does not look right as the result lablelled `MyTextsc` shows (I modified it slightly to apply a `\tiny` size change):

[image]

The results are not very good, so wondering if others have other suggestions?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AMorPMTextModeTextsc}[1]{%
        \@ifnextchar{.}%
            {\textsc{\,{\small#1}}}%
            {\textsc{\,{\small#1}}\xspace}%
}%

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/4301
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MyTextsc}[1]{%
 \edef\@tempa{\f@series}\edef\@tempb{\bfdefault}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \uppercase{{\tiny#1}}% \small here seems to do nothing
 \else
  {\scshape\small#1}%
 \fi }

\newcommand*{\AMorPMTextModeMyTextsc}[1]{%
        \@ifnextchar{.}%
            {\MyTextsc{\,{#1}}}%
            {\MyTextsc{\,{#1}}\xspace}%
}%

\makeatother


\newcommand{\PrintText}[1]{%
\makebox[8.0em][l]{Using \textbackslash#1:} 5:00\PM to 8:00\PM.\par
\makebox[8.0em][l]{Using \textbackslash#1:} \textbf{5:00\PM to 8:00\PM.}
}%

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\AM}{\AMorPMTextModeTextsc{am}}%
\newcommand{\PM}{\AMorPMTextModeTextsc{pm}}%
\PrintText{textsc}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\AM}{\AMorPMTextModeMyTextsc{am}}%
\renewcommand{\PM}{\AMorPMTextModeMyTextsc{pm}}%
\PrintText{MyTextsc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you don't want to switch to a different font that provides bold small caps (like Linux Libertine)?

Comment: Or switch to 24h format :P

Comment: @Caramdir: I don't mind switching fonts but not something I had dived into, but any suggestions for fonts to use that work in with math mode are fine.

Comment: @PeterGrill: MinionPro is nice, it's not a free font though. The basic cuts are included in the Adobe Reader package (though I did not read the licence...). LaTeX support is available [in the FontPro package](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good rule of thumb for scaling uppercase to match (poorly) small caps is to use a factor 0.8 of the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\maybefakesc}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\f@series}{\bfdefault}=\z@
    {\fontsize{\dimexpr0.8\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{0}\selectfont\uppercase{#1}}%
  \else
    \textsc{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\AM{\,\maybefakesc{am}\xspace}
\newcommand\PM{\,\maybefakesc{pm}\xspace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\bfseries 5:00\AM to 8:00\AM}

5:00\AM to 8:00\AM

\textbf{\AM}\AM

\Huge\textbf{\AM}\AM

\end{document}
```

Notice that your test of a following period is useless if you adopt `\xspace`.

[image]

It may seem too high, when compared side by side, but boldface always has some overshoot. Refine at will.

Note. If the text you pass to `\maybefakesc` can be more complicated than a simple string of ASCII characters, change `\uppercase` into `\MakeUppercase`.

Answer (score 3):

My method relies on the **relsize** package. Please, if needed, read the package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xspace}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\declarescsize{\@testopt\declare@scsize{1}}
\def\declare@scsize[#1]{%
  \protected\def\makesc##1{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\f@series}{\bfdefault}=\z@
      \uppercase{{\relsize{#1}{##1}}}%
   \else
      \textsc{##1}%
   \fi
  }%
}
\newcommand\AM{\,\makesc{am}\xspace}
\newcommand\PM{\,\makesc{pm}\xspace}
\makeatother

% You can change the scale by calling \declarescsize:
\declarescsize[-1.2]

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
{\bfseries 5:00\AM to 8:00\AM}

5:00\AM to 8:00\AM

\textbf{\AM}\AM

\par\bigskip
{\Huge\textbf{\AM}\AM}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you a) add a picture of the output and b) add a few words to explain your approach, how it solves the problem?

Comment: There's no real need to use `\protected` and `\@testopt`, since `\newcommand\declarescsize[1][1]{...}` would "robustify" `\declarescsize` anyway. You end up with defining two macros anyway.

Comment: @egreg: Please I don't understand this one. Does `\newcommand` robustify? Maybe we have many connotations of "robustify". And doesn't `\newcommand` use `\@testopt` internally?

Comment: The commands *with an optional argument* defined with `\newcommand[n][...]{...}` *are* robust: they survive being used in moving arguments. They use `\@testopt`, of course, but the kernel takes precautions in order that the command is written unexpanded in the auxiliary files.