# How to type this arrow in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I need an arrow like the following:

[image]

I tried

```
\newcommand{\wedgearrow}{\mathrel{/}\joinrel\ssearrow} %stmaryrd
```

but it doesn't work well.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No `tikz`...works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stmaryrd}
\newsavebox\wedgearrowbaseline
\savebox\wedgearrowbaseline{$\scalerel{%
  \ooalign{\kern.05pt/\cr/}\mkern-8.5mu}{\ssearrow}$}
\newcommand{\wedgearrow}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \usebox{\wedgearrowbaseline}}{X}}} %stmaryrd
\begin{document}
$K\wedgearrow L$

$\scriptstyle K\wedgearrow L$

$\scriptscriptstyle K\wedgearrow L$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Similar to [Ahrtaler's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484220/121799), the difference being that it also cooperates with subscripts (and all math styles) and becomes bold if one is in bold mode. I recommend [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799) for further reading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\tikzset{wedge arrow/.style={->,line cap=round,line join=round}}
\newcommand{\wedgearrow}{\checkbold\tmp%
\ensuremath{\mathrel{%
\mathchoice{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.1ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em},wedge arrow](0,0) -- (60:0.6em) -- ++ (-60:0.6em);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.1ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em},wedge arrow](0,0) -- (60:0.6em) -- ++ (-60:0.6em);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.075ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.045em},wedge arrow](0,0) -- (60:0.45em) -- ++(-60:0.45em);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.06ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.035em},wedge arrow](0,0) -- (60:0.35em) -- ++ (-60:0.35em);}
}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\wedgearrow B_{C\wedgearrow D}$ {\Large $A\wedgearrow B_{C\wedgearrow D}$}

\boldmath$A\wedgearrow B_{C\wedgearrow D}$ {\Large $A\wedgearrow B_{C\wedgearrow D}$}
\unboldmath
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDITs**:

1. added `\mathrel` at [Eclipse Sun's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484215/how-to-type-this-arrow-in-math-mode/484221?noredirect=1#comment1224300_484221).
2. Made the macro detect the font weight, too, so the arrow goes bold in `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`, just like the standard arrows.
3. Added round line caps and joins, motivated by [Joey's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484215/how-to-type-this-arrow-in-math-mode/484221?noredirect=1#comment1224361_484221).

Comment: looks a bit smarter than mine. But it is harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks! Should we use something like `\mathrel` so that the spacing looks better?

Comment: @EclipseSun Yes, that's a great suggestion!

Comment: @EclipseSun Now it also sees the font weight, Of course, you can change the appearance (angles, baseline, line width etc.) at will without the need to learn many commands, and the line joins and so on are automatically appealing. Loading Ti*k*Z *only for that might be a bit much, but if you are considering inventing more symbols that might be a good choice.

Comment: Don't the default arrows (in CM at least) have round line caps instead of flat?

Comment: @Joey One could just add `line cap=round` ....

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do something like that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\textsize}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\wedgearrow}{%
    \resizebox {!} {\textsize} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, line width = 2pt] (0,0) -- (.5,1) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
    Hi this \wedgearrow is a wedgearrow
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `\mathpalette`: the slash is resized to the same vertical size as the arrow, a bit widened for compensating the stroke width and vertically placed to fit.

Some manual adjustment is needed for getting the tops to meet.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\wedgearrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\wedge@arrow\relax}}
\newcommand{\wedge@arrow}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\ssearrow$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\resizebox{!}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1/$}}}%
  \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{\scalebox{1.1}[1]{\box\tw@}}% slash
  \mathchoice{\mkern-2.5mu}{\mkern-2.5mu}{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3.5mu}%
  \box\z@ % arrow
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$K\wedgearrow L_{K\wedgearrow L_{K\wedgearrow L}}$

{\Huge$K\wedgearrow L$}

\end{document}
```

[image]