# How to create a command for the "strange m" symbol in latex?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I am wanting to use the "strange m" symbol in my latex code.

I had hoped to use the scorpio symbol, but have been unable to find a scorpio command that produces what I am looking for. The two that I have found were not exactly what I had in mind.

I essentially want the symbol to be like the greek letter eta, but with two bumps instead of one.

Unfortunately, I am unsure of how to construct NEW symbols in latex.

[image: These are the scorpio symbols]

[image: These are more like the symbol I want]

Currently the best I have is this symbol, but it has broken apart slightly

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\Scorpio
\end{document}`?

Comment: Are you looking for `\scorpio` (`wasysym` package), `\Scorpio` (`marvsym` package), or `\Scorpio` (`startfont` package)?

Comment: I don't want scorpio exactly. I had hoped the scorpio symbol would work, but I've seen both and neither were the symbol I want :/

I just want an extra bump on eta. 

Like eta, but an m with a flick instead of an n with a flick

Comment: Nice question. Upvoted and retracted close vote.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do it yourself joining `m` and `\eta` with `\clipbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\emeta}{\clipbox{0em -1ex .3em -1ex}{$m$}\clipbox{.3em -1ex 0em -1ex}{$\eta$}}
\begin{document}
\[
m\eta
\]
\[
\emeta
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use relative units instead of absolute ones such that this symbol can also be used in subscripts, footnotes and so on?

Comment: I have just implemented the symbol and it doesn't quite line up :/

Comment: I have added a picture of the current state of the symbol, in the post.

Comment: @CarLaTeX 


\newcommand{\emeta}{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 3pt -1pt}{$m$}\clipbox{3pt 0pt 0pt -1pt}{$\eta$}}

I just added this and then wrote

$ \emeta $ 

later in the paper

Comment: @CarLaTeX Great .... almost. ;-) If you load `amsmath` and do `{\Large $\boldsymbol{\emeta}$}` it does not quite line up, so you may need to distinguish between bold and not bold. (A bold m is wider than a nonbold one, and 1em measures the width of the m.) I will be happy to remove the corresponding discussion of my answer if you ask me to.

Comment: @marmot I hope the OP doesn't have to use it in bold, it's too complicated to foresee every usage :)

Comment: It appears the second component is a tiny bit lower than it should be so I would recommend shifting the second component upwards by a millimetre or so

Comment: @OliverMorrison See the new version, Jack Lam found an error in the previous one!

Answer (score 6):

The Miama Nueva font is on CTAN and distributed with TeX Live.

[image: miama]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=1]{miama}

\begin{document}
\miama{m}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As discussed under [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799), you can always build your own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\freakym}{\checkbold\tmp%
\def\mpath{(0,1ex) to[out=0,in=70] (0.2em,0) to[out=70,in=180]
(0.4em,1ex) to[out=0,in=70] (0.6em,0) to[out=70,in=180]
(0.8em,1ex)  to[out=0,in=70] (1em,0) to[out=-110,in=-90,looseness=2.5] 
(1.15em,-0.2ex)}
\ensuremath{\mathchoice{%
\tikz[baseline=0ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em}] \mpath;}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=0ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em}] \mpath;}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=0ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.045em},scale=0.75]
\mpath;}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=0ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.035em},scale=0.6]
\mpath;}
}}}
\begin{document}

\freakym

$A\freakym B_{C\freakym D}$ {\Large $A\freakym B_{C\freakym D}$}

\boldmath$A\freakym B_{C\freakym D}$ {\Large $A\freakym B_{C\freakym D}$}
\unboldmath
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun a version strongly inspired by CarLaTeX. I will be happy to remove this part of my answer if she adds something along these lines to her nice answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else%
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\newcommand\clippym{\checkbold\tmp%
\tikz[baseline=(m.base)]{\begin{scope}
\clip(-0.4em,0) rectangle (0.15em,1.8ex); 
\node[anchor=south,inner sep=0pt](m){$m$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.12em]
\clip(0,-0.6ex) rectangle (0.4em,1.8ex); 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt](m) at(-0.2725em-\tmp*0.075em,-0.4ex) {$\eta$};
\end{scope}}}
\begin{document}
\clippym\footnote{Full credit for $\clippym$ goes to CarLaTeX.}

{\Large \clippym}

$\boldsymbol{\clippym}$

{\Large $\boldsymbol{\clippym}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]