# A Strange Latex Symbol

Tags: symbols, math-operators

In the book ``All of statistics A Concise Course in Statistical Inference'' of Larry Wasserman has a strange symbol, and look like a coil spring ... How can I use it in LaTeX?
[image: here is the strange symbol]

Comment: Similar one: `\gluon` from Table 308 from "the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list”

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE. I would like to draw your attention to the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799). I base my proposal on the Ti*k*Z answer there. A simple (but scalable) coil can be produced with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand\Wasserman{\tikz[baseline=-0.8ex]{\draw[line width=0.07em,decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=0.45em,amplitude=0.8ex}] (0,0) -- (2em,0);}}
\begin{document}
\[ X_1 \Wasserman X_2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some extra amount of work you can make it "boldable" and comply with the different math styles (the above version already becomes large if you say `\large`, of course outside of math mode).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\WassermanCoil}{\checkbold\tmp%
\ensuremath{\mathrel{%
\mathchoice{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.8ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em},decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=0.45em,amplitude=0.8ex}] (0,0) -- (2em,0);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.8ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em},decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=0.45em,amplitude=0.8ex}] (0,0) -- (2em,0);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.6ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.045em},decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=0.36em,amplitude=0.6ex}] (0,0) -- (1.6em,0);}
}{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.45ex]{\draw[line width={(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.035em},decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=0.25em,amplitude=0.45ex}] (0,0) -- (1.2em,0);}
}}}}
\begin{document}
\[ X_1 \WassermanCoil X_2 X_{Y_1 \WassermanCoil Y_2}\]
\boldmath
\[ X_1 \WassermanCoil X_2 X_{Y_1 \WassermanCoil Y_2}\]
\unboldmath

{\Large A\WassermanCoil B} {\Huge A\WassermanCoil B} {\small A\WassermanCoil B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One could go even more fancy by employing a [3d coil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449706/121799) but I am not going to spell this out unless asked to.

Another thing you can do is to follow [CarLaTeX's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486051/121799) and use `trimpclip` to clip away one coil of the `\gluon` (that has been [mentioned in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487943/a-strange-latex-symbol#comment1232328_487943) just now) to get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}    
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\WassermanCoil}{\clipbox{0em -1ex 1.65em -1ex}{\gluon}%
\clipbox{1.7em -1ex 0em -1ex}{\gluon}}
\begin{document}
\[
X_1\WassermanCoil X_2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If the symbol `\gluon` hadn't existed, or you drew the symbol with TikZ or you can use, for example, the package `circuitikz`. Adding also the `scalerel` package allows you to adjust the size of the symbol as you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\ngluon}{\scaleobj{.7}{\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (.65,0) to [cute inductor] (1.5,0) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{document} 
$X_1\,\ngluon\, X_2|X_3$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `cute inductor` inside Ti*k*Z commands?! Oh my gosh what a fantastic idea! :D.

Comment: @manooooh I was just thinking about the circuits and I read the manual. Thanks always dear friend.