# Using new command for a tikz draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I created a Ti*k*Z  picture using `\newcommand` and I want to use it as a subscript. The problem is that it is too big, is there a way I can make it smaller?

Here's what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[border = 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\test}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(1,1);
    \draw (0,1) -- (0.5-0.05,0.5+0.05);
    \draw (1,0) -- (0.5+0.05,0.5-0.05);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    $Something_{\test}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\draw (0,1) -- (0.5-0.05,0.5+0.05);
\draw (1,0) -- (0.5+0.05,0.5-0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}}
$X_{\test[scale=0.2]}$
\end{document}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Your proposal works nicely if you use `scale` to scale the picture down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\draw (0,1) -- (0.5-0.05,0.5+0.05);
\draw (1,0) -- (0.5+0.05,0.5-0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}}
$X_{\test[scale=0.2]}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, often one wants to define a new symbol that scales with the text and becomes bold when the surroundings are, adapts the color of is ambient text and so on. Here is a way of achieving this with your command as starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\somedrawing}{(0,0)--(0.7em,0.7em)  (0,0.7em) -- (0.35em-0.07em,0.35em+0.07em)
 (0.7em,0) -- (0.35em+0.07em,0.35em-0.07em)}
\newcommand{\myX}{\checkbold\tmp%
\ensuremath{\mathrel{%
\mathchoice{%
\tikz{\draw[line width={1.2*(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em}]\somedrawing;}
}{%
\tikz{\draw[line width={1.2*(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.06em}]\somedrawing;}
}{%
\tikz{\draw[line width={1.2*(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.045em}]\somedrawing;}
}{%
\tikz{\draw[line width={1.2*(1+0.33*\tmp)*0.035em}]\somedrawing;}
}}}}
\newcommand{\test}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.07ex] ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$X_{\myX}$ {\Large $\myX_{\myX}$} {\boldmath $X_{\myX}$ \textcolor{blue}{\Large $\myX_{\myX}$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further information can be found in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799), and I am using the Ti*k*Zy answer from there.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @AnaEmiliadeOrellana Glad to hear! If this answer works for you, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @marmot's answer but the parameter passed (a number) is the scale-down size and you could simply the `\test` command without passing any parameters (the scale factor is set to 0.2 by default). Also, I have make the drawing of the command easier, I drew a thick white line and then a smaller black line.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border = 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\test}[1][0.2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
        \draw[] (0,0)--(1,1);
        \draw[very thick, white] (1,0)--(0,1); % The white separation
        \draw[] (1,0)--(0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    Default size \test, in mathmode: $Something_{\test[0.125]}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that the OP's way of drawing this is better since it does also look good on a non-white background.

Comment: That's very true, I just thought that it might be a bit easier in terms of coding. Is there another (easier) way to obtain the result that also renders well on non-white background?

Comment: Yes, `dash pattern`.

Comment: Oh true, thanks!