Need to create a math symbol
I want to create a math symbol of the following form--

such that I would be able to change the value of i, i.e., it will be an external input to the function defined.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Hi, welcome. You need to give more info... is the symbol an operator? A normal symbol? A relation symbol? Should it work in super- and subscripts? You can try with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413073/creating-custom-mathematical-symbols and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506021/defining-a-new-mathematical-symbol-without-argument and post your attempt...

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871

For your information, this site allows you to find symbols after drawing them by hand: Detexify

Here's one way that works across math scripts.
I have used \mathord to make it act as a variable (or constant) in terms of spacing.  If it was an operator of some sort, the \mathord could be changed to \mathbin or \mathrel, as appropriate.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathord{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{-.25\LMpt}{c}{-1\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\cdot}{\SavedStyle\Delta}%
}}}}
\begin{document}
$\mysym_i = 0$

$\scriptstyle\mysym_j = 1$

$\scriptscriptstyle\mysym_k = 2$
\end{document}


If you preferred an actual triangle, rather than a Greek \Delta, then this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathord{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle\cdot}{\SavedStyle\triangle}%
}}}}
\begin{document}
$\mysym_i = 0$

$\scriptstyle\mysym_j = 1$

$\scriptscriptstyle\mysym_k = 2$
\end{document}



The logix package (requires an unicode-aware engine like lualatex) has a similar symbol:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{logix}

\begin{document}

\[
  \LogNonCont_i
\]

\[
  \DottedUpTriangle_i
\]

\end{document}



In the set font stix there is a triangle with dot. You can import only the symbol \trianglecdot. The code is with the default font of Computer Modern=CM is:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}       {LS2}{stixtt}   {m} {n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglecdot}{\mathord}{arrows3}{"8B}
\begin{document}

$\trianglecdot_i$ symbol is taken from the STIX font. The other font is the default CM.
\[\trianglecdot_i(x,y)=\sum m(i)_{\trianglecdot}(x^2+y^2)\]

\end{document}



With the standard fonts:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\triangledot}{\mathord{\mathpalette\triangledot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\triangledot@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\triangle$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1\cdot$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x+\triangledot_{i}+y$

$\scriptstyle x+\triangledot+y$

\end{document}


I tested it also with fourier, but with NewTX or kpfonts the result is not satisfying.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\triangledot}{\mathord{\mathpalette\triangledot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\triangledot@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\triangle}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{-0.2\height}[0pt][0pt]{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\triangle$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x+\triangledot_{i}+y$

$\scriptstyle x+\triangledot+y$

\end{document}


The same code works for kpfonts:

If you use a different math font, experiment different amounts of raising(or lowering) on the basis of the second version.
