# Kaktovik inupiaq numerals

Tags: symbols

How can I insert [these numeral symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaktovik_Inupiaq_numerals)

[image]

in LaTeX? Are these available via some package?

Comment: do you have a font with them (if not they could be included as graphics)]

Comment: There seems to be one non-free font that provides them: https://www.linguistsoftware.com/linup.htm. None of the free fonts seem to.

Comment: @AlanMunn Interesting! They look more fancy than the above ones. One could still get similar characters with the `calligraphy` library, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could build them with Ti*k*Z, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480818) for a discussion. Ti*k*Z does not only allow us to draw these things, but it also comes with all the means to do the modulo arithmetic to make this enterprise a bit enjoyable. (One *could* make it much more "interesting" and shorter using tricks like the `turtle` library. However, this post is to give you a start without these gimmicks.) This implements the numbers 1-20. Their font size and weight adjusts itself to the surrounding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\tikzset{pics/InupiaqNo/.cd,
1/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.5ex,0);}},
2/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.4ex,0)-- (0.8ex,1ex);}},
3/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.3ex,0)-- (0.6ex,1ex) -- (0.9ex,0ex);}},
4/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.25ex,0)-- (0.5ex,1ex) -- (0.75ex,0ex)-- (1ex,1ex) ;}},
5/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.4ex);}},
10/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.3ex) -- (0,0.6ex);}},
15/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.25ex) -- (0,0.5ex) --(1ex,0.75ex);}},
}
\newcommand{\InupiaqNo}[2][]{\checkbold\tmp%
\scalerel*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0em,line width={(1+0.45*\tmp)*0.06em},
    line cap=round,line join=round,#1]
\ifnum#2>0
 \ifnum#2<21
  \ifnum#2=20
   \draw[looseness=1.6] (0,1ex) to[out=-45,in=0] (0.5ex,0) to[out=180,in=-135] (1ex,1ex);
   \path (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \else 
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SingleDigits}{Mod(#2,5)}%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FiveDigits}{int(#2/5)*5}%
   \path \ifnum\SingleDigits=0 \else pic{InupiaqNo/\SingleDigits} \fi
   \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 \else (0,1.2ex) pic{InupiaqNo/\FiveDigits} \fi
    (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \fi   
 \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}{M}%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+10)}] in {1,...,10}
{$\X:~\InupiaqNo{\X}\ifnum\X=10 \quad~\,\else\qquad\fi\Y:~\InupiaqNo{\Y}$\par}

{\Large $12:~\InupiaqNo{12}$} {\Large\boldmath $12:~\InupiaqNo{12}$} 
{\Huge $7:~\InupiaqNo{7}$} {\Huge\boldmath $17:~\InupiaqNo{17}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Made them single-stroke characters, thanks to @DavidCarlisle for reminding me.

It might be just me but somehow these symbols remind me of something...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\tikzset{pics/InupiaqNo/.cd,
1/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.5ex,0);}},
2/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.4ex,0)-- (0.8ex,1ex);}},
3/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.3ex,0)-- (0.6ex,1ex) -- (0.9ex,0ex);}},
4/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.25ex,0)-- (0.5ex,1ex) -- (0.75ex,0ex)-- (1ex,1ex) ;}},
5/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.4ex);}},
10/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.3ex) -- (0,0.6ex);}},
15/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.25ex) -- (0,0.5ex) --(1ex,0.75ex);}},
}
\newcommand{\InupiaqNo}[2][]{\checkbold\tmp%
\scalerel*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0em,line width={(1+0.45*\tmp)*0.06em},
    line cap=round,line join=round,#1]
\ifnum#2>0
 \ifnum#2<21
  \ifnum#2=20
   \draw[looseness=1.6] (0,1ex) to[out=-45,in=0] (0.5ex,0) to[out=180,in=-135] (1ex,1ex);
   \path (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \else 
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SingleDigits}{Mod(#2,5)}%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FiveDigits}{int(#2/5)*5}%
   \path \ifnum\SingleDigits=0 \else pic{InupiaqNo/\SingleDigits} \fi
   \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 \else (0,1.2ex) pic{InupiaqNo/\FiveDigits} \fi
    (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \fi   
 \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}{M}%
}
\begin{document}
\Huge\noindent\pagecolor{black}\color{green}\foreach \X in {1,...,496}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myrnd}{1+20*rnd}\InupiaqNo{\myrnd}\space}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Just for fun: played a bit with the cool `calligraphy` library. There is a lot room for improvement (on my side, of course) but this was just to try out things. It also stores the characters in saveboxes which is advantageous if you use lots of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}
\tikzset{pics/InupiaqNo/.cd,
1/.style={code={\calligraphy \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 (0,1ex) \else (0,1.2ex)\fi to[bend right=10]  (0.5ex,0);}},
2/.style={code={\calligraphy \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 (0,1ex) \else (0,1.2ex)\fi
to[bend right=10] (0.4ex,0) to[bend left=10] (0.8ex,1ex);}},
3/.style={code={\calligraphy \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 (0,1ex) \else (0,1.2ex)\fi
to[bend right=10] (0.3ex,0) to[bend left=10] (0.6ex,1ex) to[bend right=10] (0.9ex,0ex);}},
4/.style={code={\calligraphy \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 (0,1ex) \else (0,1.2ex)\fi
to[bend right=10] (0.25ex,0) to[bend left=10] (0.5ex,1ex) to[bend right=10]
(0.75ex,0ex) to[bend left=10] (1ex,1ex) ;}},
5/.style={code={\calligraphy (0,0) to[bend right=10] (1ex,0.4ex);}},
10/.style={code={\calligraphy (0,0) to[bend right=10] (1ex,0.3ex) to[bend
left=10] (0,0.6ex);}},
15/.style={code={\calligraphy (1ex,0.75ex) to[bend left=10] (0,0.5ex)
 to[bend right=10] (1ex,0.25ex) to[bend left=10] (0,0);}},
}
\newcommand{\InupiaqNoTikZ}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0em,#1]
\ifnum#2>0
 \ifnum#2<21
  \ifnum#2=20
   \pen (-90:{0.06ex})  -- (90:{0.06ex});
   \calligraphy[light,looseness=1.6] (0,1ex) to[out=-45,in=0] (0.5ex,0) to[out=180,in=-135] (1ex,1ex);
   \path (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \else 
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SingleDigits}{Mod(#2,5)}%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FiveDigits}{int(#2/5)*5}%
   \pen (-95:{0.08em})  -- (85:{0.08em});
   \path \ifnum\SingleDigits=0 \else pic{InupiaqNo/\SingleDigits} \fi;
   \pen (-180:{0.08em}) -- (0:{0.08em});
   \path \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 \else (0.08ex,1.28ex) pic{InupiaqNo/\FiveDigits} \fi
    (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
   \ifnum\the\numexpr\SingleDigits*\FiveDigits>0
   \fi
  \fi   
 \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \X in {1,...,20}
{\expandafter\newsavebox\csname InupiaqBox\X\endcsname
\global\expandafter\sbox\csname InupiaqBox\X\endcsname{\InupiaqNoTikZ{\X}}}

\newcommand{\InupiaqNo}[1]{\scalerel*{\expandafter\usebox\csname InupiaqBox#1\endcsname}{M}%
}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\foreach \X in {1,...,20} {\X:\InupiaqNo{\X}\space}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice but my understanding from https://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-inupiaq/en/esi/ and elsewhere that they are supposed to be a singe stroke so connected top bars

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Now they are.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small adjustment to the discussion.  The symbol used above for 20 is actually the digit for 0 in the base 20 numeral system used by Kaktovik, not the symbol for 20 see [Bartley, Wm. Clark "Making the Old Way Count"](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625225547/http://ankn.uaf.edu/SOP/SOPv2i1.pdf) and [Silva, Eduardo Marín; Miller, Kirk; Strand, Catherine "Unicode request for Kaktovik numerals (L2/21-058R)"](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2021/21058r-kaktovik-numerals.pdf). 20 is written as the digit for 1 followed by the digit for 0.

This revision of the the first (most simple) LaTeX solution by @user194703 addresses this issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \edef\@tempa{\math@version}\edef\@tempb{bold}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \else
  \def#1{0}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\tikzset{pics/InupiaqNo/.cd,
1/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.5ex,0);}},
2/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.4ex,0)-- (0.8ex,1ex);}},
3/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.3ex,0)-- (0.6ex,1ex) -- (0.9ex,0ex);}},
4/.style={code={\draw \ifnum\FiveDigits>0 (0,1.2ex) \else (0,1ex)\fi -- (0.25ex,0)-- (0.5ex,1ex) -- (0.75ex,0ex)-- (1ex,1ex) ;}},
5/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.4ex);}},
10/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.3ex) -- (0,0.6ex);}},
15/.style={code={\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0.25ex) -- (0,0.5ex) --(1ex,0.75ex);}},
}
\newcommand{\InupiaqNo}[2][]{\checkbold\tmp%
\scalerel*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0em,line width={(1+0.45*\tmp)*0.06em},
    line cap=round,line join=round,#1]
\ifnum#2>0
 \ifnum#2<21
  \ifnum#2=20
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SingleDigits}{1}%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FiveDigits}{0}%
   \path \ifnum\SingleDigits=0 \else pic{InupiaqNo/\SingleDigits} \fi
   \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 \else (0,1.2ex) pic{InupiaqNo/\FiveDigits} \fi
   (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
   \begin{scope} [xshift=1ex,yshift=0ex]
   \draw[looseness=1.6] (0,1ex) to[out=-45,in=0] (0.5ex,0) to[out=180,in=-135] (1ex,1ex);
   \path (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
   \end{scope}
  \else 
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SingleDigits}{Mod(#2,5)}%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FiveDigits}{int(#2/5)*5}%
   \path \ifnum\SingleDigits=0 \else pic{InupiaqNo/\SingleDigits} \fi
   \ifnum\FiveDigits=0 \else (0,1.2ex) pic{InupiaqNo/\FiveDigits} \fi
    (0,0) (1ex,2ex);
  \fi   
 \fi
\else
 \draw[looseness=1.6] (0,1ex) to[out=-45,in=0] (0.5ex,0) to[out=180,in=-135] (1ex,1ex);
 \path (0,0) (1ex,2ex); 
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}{M}%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+10)}] in {1,...,10}
{$\X:~\InupiaqNo{\X}\ifnum\X=10 \quad~\,\else\qquad\fi\Y:~\InupiaqNo{\Y}$\par}

{\Large $12:~\InupiaqNo{12}$} {\Large\boldmath $12:~\InupiaqNo{12}$} 
{\Huge $7:~\InupiaqNo{7}$} {\Huge\boldmath $17:~\InupiaqNo{17}$}
\end{document}
```