# Possible values for \fontseries and \fontshape

Tags: fonts

What are the possible values for `\fontseries` and `\fontshape`? I'm aware of

```
\fontseries{m}
\fontseries{bx}

\fontshape{n}
\fontshape{it}
```

But I'm sure there're more of them.

Comment: There's really no fixed set. The possible values depend on what's set up in the `.fd` file for the encoding-family pair.

Comment: @egreg Now I've found (opening the `.fd` file) that my font has `l` for "light", and even it has `itsc` for italic small caps...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Series**, any combination of weight and width is [in theory] possible:

```
weight                    width
Ultra Light       ul      Ultra Condensed     uc    
Extra Light       el      Extra Condensed     ec    
Light             l       Condensed            c      
Semi Light        sl      Semi Condensed      sc    
Medium (normal)   m
Semi Bold         sb      Semi Expanded       sx    
Bold              b       Expanded             x 
Extra Bold        eb      Extra Expanded      ex 
Ultra Bold        ub      Ultra Expanded      ux
```

**Shape:**

```
upright (normal)   n 
italic             it
slanted/oblique    sl 
small caps         sc
upright italic     ui
outline            ol
```

It depends to the definition of the font, if there are less or more ... 
For the current TL 2012 we get the following values for the series:

```
b,bc,bm,bux,bx,c,cl,d,db,dbuc,eb,ebc,ebx,el,f,g,i,l,lc,lux,lx,m,mb,mc,muc,mx,n,nx,
ny,o,s,sb,sbc,sbx,sl,ub,ubc,ubx,ux,w,x,xl,z
```

and for the shape:

```
a,ac,b,bc,bl,bx,cal,crml,ds,fic,fr,fsc,g,gi,gu,i,ic,Iit,in,In,Isc,Isl,it,itsc,iv,jm,Jm,
kfn,l,li,n,na,ns,o,oi,oj,ol,os,out,p,r,ro,rs,s,sc,scit,sco,scsl,scui,sf,si,sk,sl,slsc,
so,sr,st,ta,tabnums,textdenomnums,textnumnums,tt,u,ui,uv,w
```

See comment below where Heiko lists some fonts which refer to the given values.

Comment: SERIES: `sbx` (kpfonts), `db` (romande), `dbuc`/`mc`/`muc`/`mux` (venturissans), `mb` (venturis2), `sbc`/`lc` (chextras), `mx` (venturissans2), `z`/`d`/`o`/`s` (libertine-legacy), `ebc`/`ubc`/`lx`/`ebx` (kurier), `cl` (opensans), `k` (allrunes). SHAPE: `scsl` (kpfonts), `si` (venturissans), `scit` (tex-gyre), `ic`/`bc` (libertine-legacy), `ac` (frcursive), `oi` (boisik), `gu`/`gi` (gillcm), `sco`/`cal`/`kfn` (kerkis), `tabnums`/`textnumnums`/`textdenomnums` (gfsartemisia), `Jm`/`jm`/`ds`/`ta`/`oj`/`so`/`sr`/`sk`/`fr`/`crml`/`s` (arabtex), `itsc`/`slsc` (bengali), `t`/`r`/`q`/`m` (allrunes)

Comment: SHAPE: `In`/`Isl`/`Iit` (cyrillic).

Comment: I also use the shape `bl` for two chessfonts (berlin and alpha in the enpassant package) to access black figurines.

Comment: @Ulrike: is that package on TL?

Comment: Great Answer! Good to see that a lot more is going on internally than `\bfseries` (which should really be called `\bxseries`) and `\itshape` might make you believe :-)

Comment: @Herbert: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Some fonts like *Cormorant* and *EB Garamond* define separate *regular* and *medium* weights, the former seeming preferred for body text, yet the latter being less heavy than semi-bold.  If `m` is recognized as designating normal text, and if a separate weight already takes the label `sb`, what labels should be used for *regular* and *medium*?

Answer (score 16):

The standard manual for such questions are [`fntguide` *LaTeX2ε font selection*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fntguide)

Here you can find the following hint:

> The most common values for the font series are:
>
> ```
> m             Medium
> b             Bold
> bx            Bold extended
> sb            Semi-bold
> c             Condensed
> ```
>
> The most common values for the font shape are:
>
> ```
> n              Normal (that is ‘upright’ or ‘roman’)
> it             Italic 
> sl             Slanted (or ‘oblique’)
> sc             Caps and small caps
> ```

You can select what you want as long as the font file exist.

Comment: This is not completely true. As egreg mentioned, the `.fd` file defines which fonts exist. That is, there could be font files which are not referred in the `.fd` and are thus never used.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I know. The list is longer. However this are the standard ones.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I meant is it can well be that the font file exists, but you still cannot select it because the `.fd` file doesn't list it.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by Herbert follows the list from *The LaTeX Companion* (on page 414 of the second edition), except that it doesn’t misleadingly display normal width as `m` (never appended to the code for the series).  The [LaTeX2e Font Selection Guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf) recommends, “Whenever  possible,  you  should  use  the  series  and shape  names  suggested  in *The LaTeX Companion*, since this will make it easier to combine new fonts with existing fonts.”  However, the qualifier matters.  Sometimes, that list isn’t sufficient.

The “[Font Installation Guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf#appendix.A](Font)” adds two additional weights, `mb` (between `m` and `sb`, usually for Medium if Semibold and Regular or Book also exist) and `db` (for Demibold, between `sb` and `b`).  A few packages, including `nfssext-cfr`, support them.  If a font has only one weight between Regular and Bold, I recommend labeling it `sb` (as, for example, Computer Modern Demi), but many fonts come in Regular, Medium, Semibold and Bold, and in this case `m`, `mb`, `sb` and `b` are the most standard names for them.

Another common case is Italic or Slanted Small Caps.  Existing fonts and packages have used `scit`, `itsc`, `scsl`, `slsc`, and `si` as a shape name for them.  [At least one coder](https://www.tug.org/applications/fontinst/mail/tex-fonts/2000/msg00358.html) put the line `\let\scit\itsc` in a font package!  Fortunately, the issue becomes obsolete if you use `fontspec`, because small caps is a font feature in OpenType, not a separate font.