# Define a new \XXseries macro for light fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Is ist possible to define a new series with `fontspec`? I tried the following but …

1. it throws an error if the font doesn’t have a light version instead of replacing the font, like `\bfseries` does. In other word there’s no fallback.
2. my `\ltseries` isn’t deactivated by `\mdseries`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
   % http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro

\newcommand{\ltseries}{%
   \addfontfeatures{UprightFont={* Light},ItalicFont={* Light Italic}}%
}

\begin{document}
\ltseries
Light

\mdseries
Regular

\bfseries
Bold
\end{document}
```

If found [Possible values for \fontseries and \fontshape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68745/4918) but it doesn’t tell how to define a new series. Furthermore this is for LaTeX and it’s NFSS, while I’m using XeTeX with `fontspec`.

Comment: `\newfontfamily` or `\newfontface`.

Comment: @Manuel: Unfortunately not. With these two I have to define the base font too and so `\ltseries` will change the family too.

Comment: If you want to definde `\ltseries` like that (and you are sure it's enough), you could redefine `\mdseries` (and `\bfseries`) to be the same but with other *UprightFont* and *ItalicFont*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a recent version of `fontspec` (v2.5a at time of writing) there is an *official interface* to declare new font shapes: One can use the `FontFace` option to define a new NFSS font face:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[
   FontFace = {lt}{n}{SourceSansPro-Light},
   FontFace = {lt}{it}{SourceSansPro-LightIt},
]{Source Sans Pro}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltseries}{\fontseries{lt}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsi}{\sishape}

\begin{document}
\ltseries
Light \textit{Italic} (not available) 

\mdseries
Regular \textit{Italic}

\bfseries
Bold \textit{Italic}

\sffamily
\ltseries
Light \textit{Italic}

\mdseries
Regular \textit{Italic}

\bfseries
Bold \textit{Italic}
\end{document}
```

This is much more comfortable than using `\DeclareFontShape`. In the example I also added the definition of `\textlt` which was missing in the other answers.

Comment: The example works perfectly. I had to put in a `Font=` because I like to use the font options for illustration purposes (e.g., `{Font=* Light, Colour=blue, Scale=2.1,}`), but then it turned out that the font files I was using (v1, from 2012) were somewhat buggy, and installing a more recent version of Source Sans Pro (2014) fixed things.

Answer (score 9):

There is no official interface. You can do it this way (this is lualatex-syntax, for the xelatex syntax check e.g. eu1lmr.fd). You should be aware that it will not work together with local font changes through `\addfontfeatures` or a local `\fontspec` as this often create a new family.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\normalfont
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{l}{n}%
     {<->    name:sourcesanspro-light:script=latn;+trep;+tlig;
      }{}

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{l}{it}%
     {<->    name:sourcesanspro-lightit:script=latn;+trep;+tlig;
      }{}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltseries}{%
\fontseries{l}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\ltseries
Light

\mdseries
Regular

\bfseries
Bold

 \normalfont
 {\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon} abc \ltseries abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ulrike's answer is correct. Adding support for arbitrary NFSS series and shapes is on my todo list (and actually the current version of GitHub allows you to name the NFSS family if you wish) -- I guess I was just putting off the idea of also adding `\textlt`/`\ltseries` to go along with everything. Always seemed like I should tackle a better way of switching between font series.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. It worked after I found out what the correct font name is :-)

Comment: (Hopefully) short question: Is it save to replace `\f@family` with `SourceSansPro(0)` or is it better to add `\sffamily` before declaring the new shapes? (I know my example used `\setmainfont` but actually it is `\setsansfont` …)

Comment: @Tobi I would use `\sffamily` + `\f@family`. The family name (the number) can change if use the font also with other features. `\sffamily` does no harm in the preamble: At `\begin{document}` a `\normalfont` is issued.

Comment: @WillRobertson: It would be very fine if one could add more series/shapes. I just did go to some length to add a semibold series in one document. Naturally it would be even better if one could add more NFSS-axes to handle e.g. variants like different number types or ligatures without ending with another family name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I change my MWE accordingly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd like to add a proper interface; care to comment on how it should look? See: <https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/170>

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hi it seems like in the meantime there was an official interface implemented and I added a new answer respecting this. Would you mind if I accept the new answer to bring it to the top? And maybe you like to add in your answer that it regards an older version. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ulrikes’s answer works fine after changing `\DeclareFontShape` in the XeTeX-way, this is how it looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
   % http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro

\begingroup % \DeclareFontShape acts globally
\makeatletter
\sffamily

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{l}{n}%
     {<->    "[SourceSansPro-Light]:mapping=tex-text"
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{l}{it}%
     {<->    "[SourceSansPro-LightIt]:mapping=tex-text"
      }{}
\endgroup % removes the effects of \sffamily and \makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltseries}{%
  \fontseries{l}\selectfont}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ltseries
Light (not available)

\mdseries
Regular

\bfseries
Bold

\sffamily
\ltseries
Light

\mdseries
Regular

\bfseries
Bold
\end{document}
```

The `\sffamily` before `\DeclareFontShape` is necessary to let `\f@family` have the right family name. At the document begin there’s a `\normalfont` so `\sffamily` doesn’t change the font for the document here …

Comment: `\makeatletter` is missing; you can enclose the two `\DeclareFontShape` commands between `\begingroup\sffamily` and `\endgroup`, changing the explicit family name by `\f@family`, because `\DeclareFontShape` is implicitly global.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I forgot the `\makeatletter` when copying the code to the MWE …