# \textlf{} for light font weight – how common?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, text-decorations, typefaces

In the [`allrunes.sty` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/allrunes) (which uses Metafont), I’ve recently seen the `\textlf` macro for the first time. It selects a light font and therefore accompanies the frequent command `\textbf` and its sibling `\textmd` for default ‘medium’.

Searching for ‘textlf’ on SX showed that this string is also a package option for [Minion Pro](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro), but there it switches on *lining figures* and it seems some other packages have a command `\textlf` that does the same.

- So I wonder, how commonly supported is `\textlf` and is there an established alternative without conflicts?
- More generally, if I’m using a typeface with fonts for many weights available (e.g. thin, light, semi-bold, bold, heavy, black …), how are they best accessed in Xe-/LuaTeX?

The second question is relevant, for instance, if I was to write a supporting package for an Open Type typeface that provided predefined `\text…` macros, which wrap `fontspec`’s `\newfontfamily` or rather the less known `\newfontface` within `\DeclareTextFontCommand`.

Comment: related: [Define a new \XXseries macro for light fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176722/define-a-new-xxseries-macro-for-light-fonts) using `\textlt`

Comment: I tend to use `\textlg`, I think. But I don't think there is a real standard here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in a texlive 2014, updated this morning I get the following from grep (with my annotation in comment at the end of each line):

```
$ grep "[^a-z]textlf[^a-z]" */*
allrunes/allrunes.sty:\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlf}{\lfseries}
baskervaldx/Baskervaldx.sty:\DeclareRobustCommand{\textlf}[1]{%    lining figures
fbb/fbb.sty:\DeclareRobustCommand{\textlf}[1]{%    lining figures
heuristica/heuristica.sty:\DeclareRobustCommand{\textlf}[1]{%    lining figures
typeface/typeface.sty:      \PassOptionsToPackage{textlf}{MinionPro}%    lining figures
xcharter/XCharter.sty:\def\textlf#1{{\lfstyle #1}}%    lining figures


$ pwd
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

So it seems that the convention is that `\textlf` where used in all other packages denotes lining figures.

Comment: Searching installed packages, why didn’t I think of that? (OTOH, I’m using BasicTeX, so several matches wouldn’t have shown up.)

Answer (score 17):

An example for `HelveticaNeue-Light`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
   ItalicFont     = HelveticaNeue-Italic,
   BoldFont       = HelveticaNeue-Bold,
   BoldItalicFont = HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic]{HelveticaNeue}
\newfontfamily\NHLight[
   ItalicFont     = HelveticaNeue-LightItalic,
   BoldFont       = HelveticaNeue-UltraLight,
   BoldItalicFont = HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic]{HelveticaNeue-Light}

\newcommand\textrmlf[1]{{\NHLight#1}}
\newcommand\textitlf[1]{{\NHLight\itshape#1}}
\let\textbflf\textrm
\newcommand\textulf[1]{{\NHLight\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand\textuitlf[1]{{\NHLight\bfseries\itshape#1}}

\begin{document}

\textrm{foo} \textbf{bar} \textit{baz} \textbf{\textit{foobar}} \par
\textrmlf{foo} \textbflf{bar} \textulf{bar} \textitlf{baz} \textuitlf{foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Next time I will ask separate questions. You answer the second one, David Carlisle answered the first one. I’m accepting his one only because it gives an objective answer, i.e. `\textlf` isn’t commonly used for light fonts, whereas you show but one good practice. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: It seems that the effect of `\textrm` and `\textbflf` is the same, which would make sense: bold x light = medium. A kind of font series arithmetic. :)

Answer (score 1):

The standard LaTeX command for this is `\fontseries{l}\selectfont`, assuming that your legacy font is installed with the official schema (or you’ve set your OpenType font family up that way with `fontspec`).

At least one other package uses a different command to select the Light weight: `nfssext-cfr` declares it as `\lgweight` and `\textlg{}` when the light font is provided as a weight.  Note that this has different behavior because it allows selecting weight and width separately.  So, for example, if you’ve currently selected Regular Condensed, `\lgweight` would select Light Condensed, but `\fontseries{l}` will select Light, because LaTeX merges Light and Condensed into the `{lc}` series.