# TeXLive-2016: Strangely, CronosPro-BoldCaptIt is loaded instead of CronosPro-BoldCapt

Tags: luatex, texlive, opentype

The file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{MinionPro}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CronosPro}
\begin{document}
MinionPro: \textbf{bold}

\textsf{CronosPro: \textbf{{bold}}}
\end{document}
```

run through lualatex from TeXLive-2015 gives a PDF file 
as expected; with lualatex from TeXLive-2016, MinionPro bold 
is displayed as expected, but for CronosPro, BoldItalics is
used instead. I'd be happy to provide the logs if a kind soul
would like to look into this strange change.

Comment: Perhaps same issue here as the following ticket: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/356. I see just now that a commit has been made, it could be worthwile to check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but, sorry, after installing luaotfload.tds.zip with luaotfload-main 2016/04/21 2.70002 in /usr/local/2016/texmf-dist/, the font selected instead of bold still is bold-italics.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your example but did not find the issue you described. I am using the stock TeXLive 2016, updated just today. The fonts are the versions from Adobe Font Folio 11 (but I don't think the versions of the fonts are issues here). Though I do have the patch in https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/pull/231 applied to `fontspec`. I am not sure if that is the issue.

Another possible reason is you need to forcefully rebuild the font name database,

```
luaotftools --update -f
```

Other than these I cannot think of any reason why it picked the wrong font

Comment: Thank you for your hint; I've recreated both the system-wide and the user's version of luaotfload-names.lua.gz with luaotfload-tool --update -f . The file contains proper descriptions of both CronosPro-BoldCapt and CronosPro-BoldCaptIt. The latter font, however, is used in my installation.

Comment: A fresh ~/.texlive2016/, after compiling my example file results in cronospro-boldit.lua and cronospro-boldcaptit.lua files in the ~./texlive2016/.../otl/ tree, while cronospro-bold.lua and cronospro-boldcapt.lua are not created. They live in ~/.texlive2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/, however.

Comment: @ErnstM. In that case I am afraid I can't help you. Maybe it is a system dependent thing. I am using the latest OS X. In addition, it should be the caption optical size selected. In my test, the CronosPro-Bold and Cronos-Regular are correctly selected. If you only have the the caption fonts, maybe it is the issue, since their naming are a bit non-conventional.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that have changed in TL 2016 with repect to luatex: First of all of course that many primitives have been changed, but also that the font loader has been rewritten in lua instead of using the fontforge libraries. While this is in principle a good idea, there surely are many bugs lurking and you are asked to report them to the bug tracker of the font loader: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/

Answer (score 1):

As long as LuaTeX suffers from bugs, install Adobe Cronos Pro for pdftex following this manual and support: https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro

There are some discussion how to get it all to work here: [Myriad Pro Condensed undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291024/4736)