# How do fonts work in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

How do fonts work in LaTeX? When I write the command:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I'm specifying how the computer will read my keyboard inputs, right? Now, the command:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

is the one supposed to be responsible for the glyphs printed for the reader, right? If this one is responsable for the fonts, what is its relation to font packages like `tgpagella` or `mathpazo`, which I can also call, but won't work without `fontenc`?

Also, where are the fonts specified in the command line

```
\usefont{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

comming from? If I specify enconding as `T1`, I still can choose between several different families `pbk` (bookman), `phv` (helvetica) and so forth. I thought, `T1` would fix the font to be used.

Can you shed some light over this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What makes you think they won't work without `fontenc`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc for the first part. The second part is covered in `texdoc fntguide`

Comment: You didn't mention the prupose for which you intend to use LaTeX. Since you mention Goudy and Bookman fonts, my guess is that you intend to do writing rather than math. If that is so, then consider using LuaTeX with fontenc, and forget about T1 and OT1. LuaTeX with fontenc will give you access to modern Open Type fonts, with all their features, and they don't have to be part of TeX.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The output encoding e.g. `T1` does, as [Bernard says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338059/), determine which characters go in which slots. But an encoding may also specify ligatures, as T1 does. For example, it tells TeX that if an `f` is followed by an `i`, it should replace the sequence of two characters with a character from a third slot which contains the `fi` ligatures.

In addition, when you load a particular encoding, LaTeX will use a particular set of definitions when you ask for various characters. For example, depending on the details of your configuration, it may set up mappings from particular sequences of characters to particular unicode characters. Because T1 includes many accented characters, for example, these can be mapped to single points in unicode. This makes it possible to search files created with T1 more easily, in many cases, than similar-looking files created using OT1. Depending on the font, the appearance will usually be superior, too. This is because TeX must create accented characters on-the-fly in OT1 rather than using the characters specially designed to represent them. For example `â` might be created from the unaccented `a` and the `^` accent, rather than using the `â`.

When you call a package such as `tgpagella`, it sets up fonts for you. You could do this directly yourself - the package is just a convenience.

A line such as

```
\usefont{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

is a lower-level command which specifies a particular font. What most font packages do is set up default document fonts or create convenient macros to access a special-purpose font.

LaTeX defines `\usefont{}{}{}{}` as follows:

```
\def\usefont#1#2#3#4{\fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}%
         \fontseries{#3}\fontshape{#4}\selectfont
         \ignorespaces}
```

Now consider a special-purpose font, such as that supported by `GoudyIn.sty`. This defines two macros as follows

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GoudyInfamily}{%
        \fontencoding{U}%
        \fontseries{xl}%
        \fontshape{n}%
        \fontfamily{GoudyIn}%
        \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\goudyin}{\GoudyInfamily}
```

You could use these commands directly in your document or you use use

```
\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}
```

every time you wanted to use the font. But that would be tedious and you'd have to remember the encoding, series, shape and family name rather than just remembering to

```
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
```

and

```
\goudyin{<text>}
```

which is somewhat more convenient.

A package such as `tgpagella` is a bit more complex, but the most interesting line for current purposes is.

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qpl}
```

This sets the default serif font to `qpl`. This means that LaTeX will try to use a font in the default text encoding (OT1 by default or something else). To do this, it looks for a font definition file `<encoding><family>.fd`. For example, `t1qpl.fd` or `ot1qpl.fd` or whatever. If it finds this, it will read the file which sets up the font.

For example, here's part of `t1qpl.fd`:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{qpl}{\qpl@set@spacing}
```

This creates a font family for `qpl` in the `T1` encoding. Once the font family is defined, the code specifies which fonts LaTeX should use for which series and shapes when this font family is active.

The series establishes both the relative width and the relative weight e.g. bold extended or light condensed or medium standard.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sc}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplb-sc}{}
```

This tells LaTeX to use the font `ec-qplb-sc` when bold small-caps are requested.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{n}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplb}{}
```

Upright bold.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{scit}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplbi-sc}{}
```

Italic small-caps bold. This is not a standard shape, so some font packages use a different name for the same shape. For example, my font packages use `si` for italic small-caps rather than `scit`.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{it}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplbi}{}
```

Bold italic.

And now the regular weight - `\mdseries`.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sc}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplr-sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{n}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{scit}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplri-sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{it}{<-> \qpl@scale ec-qplri}{}
```

That's all the fonts provided. However, the default for `\bfseries` in LaTeX is not `b` but `bx`. This font doesn't provide `bx`, so LaTeX will have to substitute something. By default, it will substitute medium and issue a warning. That isn't great. We'd probably prefer it to substitute bold `b` rather than medium `m` and we probably don't want a warning every time we use bold either.

Fortunately, the font definitions specify suitable substitutions.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * qpl/b/sc}{}
```

If small-caps bold extended is requested, 'silently' substitute bold small-caps. That is, use bold not medium and don't issue a warning.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * qpl/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{bx}{scit}{<->ssub * qpl/b/scit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * qpl/b/it}{}
```

This font has italics but not oblique. By default, LaTeX will substitute upright if oblique is requested. However, in this case

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sl}{<->sub * qpl/b/it}{}
```

tells LaTeX to substitute italic bold for bold oblique. This substitution is not silent - the user is more likely to want to know about this, so LaTeX will issue a warning.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sl}{<->sub * qpl/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{scsl}{<->sub * qpl/b/scit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{scsl}{<->sub * qpl/m/scit}{}
```

*The following is somewhat simplified in order to provide an overall picture of the process which follows. Otherwise the number of possible complications and possibilities, along with every detail, would result in an explanation which was clear as the proverbial mud. (You may think it is pretty swamp-like already, but believe me when I say that it could get much worse.)*

## *Caveat emptor ...*

Once LaTeX knows the font it needs to find, it tries to find a TeX font of that name.

Let's say it needs `ec-qplr-sc` because you either loaded `tgpagella` and then said

```
\scshape
```

or

```
\textsc{}
```

or because you said

```
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{qpl}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{sc}\selectfont
```

or

```
\usefont{T1}{qpl}{m}{sc}
```

Then LaTeX will look for a TeX Font Metric file `ec-qplr-sc.tfm`. This file provides LaTeX with a variety of information. In particular, it tells TeX the size of the box needed for each character and how to shift boxes left or right depending on which box comes immediately before or immediately after. It may also tell TeX to replace a sequence of two boxes by a third box, for example. It also provides some general information about the font's natural size etc.

If you compile with LaTeX, that's it. The DVI just contains information about boxes. It is up to the viewer or the post-processor to figure out what to put in each box. If you are compiling with pdfLaTeX, that needs to be done as part and parcel of compilation.

To find out what to put in each box, pdfTeX or the DVI viewer or post-processor must figure out where the information to draw the glyphs for the characters is.

To do this, it looks for a line in a `.map` file. Which `.map` file depends on the current engine or post-processor. Let's suppose you are using pdfTeX, then it will consult `pdftex.map` and look for the relevant line.

```
ec-qplr-sc TeXGyrePagella-Regular " encqecsc ReEncodeFont " <q-ec-sc.enc <qplr.pfb
```

This tells pdfTeX to re-encode the font in `qplr.pfb` using the `q-ec-sc.enc` encoding. This means it knows that the information on how to draw the glyphs is in `qplr.pfb` but the information is not in the order required. `q-ec-sc.enc` tells pdfTeX how to find the information for a character in the PFB even though the characters in the PFB are not in the same order as the current output encoding.

This is the simple case. If virtual fonts are involved, then things get a bit more complicated. However, that's not the case for `qpl`, so the story so far is sufficient.

Comment: And then there are virtual fonts. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder There's a reason I left them to the last sentence! Do you think I should cover them also? I thought it might make LaTeX's fonts sound a little complicated.

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Sorry for the noise. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Do you have any source on those and info why it gets more messy? @cfr a short note would be appreciated :) ... Great post, tbh it contained way more info than I was looking for or expected. Learned more than I wanted. However, your definition `\usefont{U}{xl}{n}{GoudyIn}` doesn't agree with `\usefont{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}` as found also [here](https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf) and [where I came from](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368154). Has there been a change or are there multiple definitions?

Comment: I was wondering about a list of all the families, [series and shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68745/possible-values-for-fontseries-and-fontshape). For the font families: While [tug.org/fontcatalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) nicely lists them, I could not find how to determine the family-name or shortcut and available combinations. [Compare also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378623/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-fontfamily-fontseries-combinations).

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming That's an error - thanks for pointing it out. For virtual fonts ... they let you do things such as combining characters from different fonts into a single font at the document level. Postscript fonts often used to provide specialised characters, small caps etc. in distinct fonts. A virtual font let you take the small caps from font 1, say, and the capitals from font 2 and produce virtual font 3. They also allow things such as fake italic, fake small-caps etc., though that's more controversial.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming Take a look at the Font Installation Guide, maybe, and the documentation on Berry names (mentioned in the question you linked). As far as I know there is no list of all fonts with series, shapes etc., even if you discount the use of system fonts with newer engines. I made a couple of lists of selected fonts for teaching. I can try to find those if you're interested, but the focus was on packages rather than family names for sessions targeting beginners/intermediate users of LaTeX in academia.

Comment: @cfr thank you for offering, but not necessary. I was more interested in all the options that I'd have, mostly for special parts of documents (ie titles), where fine-tuning is important.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming The Font Catalogue is the best resource I know of. Just make sure you're picking type1 - metafont/pk look awful in PDF.

Answer (score 12):

For LaTeX, more precisely for the NFSS (New Font Selection Scheme), a font is characterised by 4 parameters:  its `encoding`, its `name`, its `weight` and its `shape`.

Font encoding only fixes the way LaTeX encodes fonts, i.e. describes which glyph is associated with each slot number:

`OT1` (the default encoding) is for alphabets without diacritics (roughly ASCII) and uses 7 bits per character.

The other encodings use 8 bits:

`T1` is for the Latin alphabet; it has most diacritics used in Western European languages.

`T2A, T2B, T2C` are cyrillic alphabets.

`LGR` is for Greek (monotonic and polytonic).

On the other hand, the font family is only a set of glyphs. For instance `phv` is the short name for LaTeX of the family `Adobe Helvetica`,and it is re-encoded for use by LaTeX (the encoding is different from Adobe encoding).

Comment: @cfr: Did I say the family name has whatever to do with the encoding?

Comment: But in practice, it's reencoded via virtual fonts either in  OT1 or T1 encoded, isn't it? You can't use them without this re-encoding, as far as I know. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Do you mean I can use , say, Adobe Garamond, without virtual fonts?

Comment: Of course. Provided you have the font in type1 postscript format. You do need TFM files etc. But you do not need virtual fonts.

Comment: Helvetica is *not* an Adobe font.

Comment: I didn't know. I happened, in the past, to set some type 1 fonts for my use, but I always created – painfully – the necessary files, including the `.vf`s.

Comment: @Mico : Didn't know that. As its LaTeX  name is **p**hv, I thought it was.

Comment: It isn't really any less painful, but you don't need the `.vf`s. However, in many cases, it makes sense to use virtual fonts e.g. if you have small-caps in a separate `.pfb` from the main font, as used to be common, I believe. But also if you wish to fake any characters, you need a virtual font (so far as I know).

Comment: Take a look at `berenisadf` where I did not use virtual fonts because no missing glyphs could be faked anyway and there was no need to combine glyphs from different postscript fonts. That is, I could use just one `.pfb` file per TeX font. However, I'm still re-encoding them to support T1, LY1 and TS1. Indeed, I'm using hacked encodings, in fact. This package supports Welsh when LY1 is used by including the accented characters not in T1 in empty slots. (And there are some encodings for swashes and things, if I remember right, too.)

Comment: @Mico `fontname` certainly thinks there is an Adobe Helvetica - see `Adobe-fonts.html`.

Comment: @cfr: I see. A beautiful piece of work, by the way. I love Bodoni, especially since I saw it in the Italian publisher Franco Maria Ricci  splendid book

Comment: @Bernard The beauty is not my doing of course, as I am not responsible for the fonts but only the LaTeX support.

Comment: I know, nonetheless, your work is tricky for me. The book I tried to mention (it switched off my comment, for some reason) was *Lewis Carroll's Photos and letters to his child friends*.