# Math mode expected value

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have a question about my expected value symbol in my latex document.
When I use `\mathbb{E}`, it actually gives me this:

[image]

rather than this:

[image]

Can someone explain this to me please, because I prefer the second symbol, it's more common in the literature than the first one.

Comment: This depends on the mathfonts you actually loaded. What's your preamble?

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{bbold}` and do `\usepackage{amssymb}` instead.

Comment: Actually I have both `\usepackage{bbold}` and `\usepackage{amssymb}`. When I removed `\usepackage{bbold}`, the expected value symbol looked exactly like I wanted, but unfortunately I have  `{\mathbb{1}}` than don't look good anymore

Comment: I tried to put `\usepackage{bbold}` before `\usepackage{amssymb}` so that `{\mathbb{1}}` works fine and the expected value symbol looks as I wanted too, but it doesn't seem to work. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: You also have `dsfont` that gives you `\mathds{1}` and has a much finer output that goes well with Computer Modern.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need to load `bbold` just for one of its symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}% expected value

\begin{document}

$\EX(f)+\bbone$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it bad to load bbold just for one symbol?

Comment: @C.Koca Because it wastes a precious math group (there are only 16 of them). Since such symbol is not subject to changes due to `\mathbf` or similar commands, it's simpler if we typeset it in text mode.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Instead of `usepackage{bbold}` which was necessary for `{\mathbb{1}}` otherwise they looked like this

[image]

I used the package `bbm` and `\mathbbm{1}`. With this both the expected value and `1` symbols look fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the same problem but with a slightly different context. I'm using LuaLaTeX with MiKTeK on TeXstudio. I wanted to use the STIX2 fonts (`\setmainfont{STIX Two Text} \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}`) while having the expectd value symbol that the original question also wanted; but the package `unicode-math`, which together with `fontspec` enables the integration of STIX2 with `amssymb`, `amsmath` and `amsfonts` (the three should be compiled before `unicode math`) made it so the expected value symbol that would come in default with `amsfonts` would be replaced with the expected value from the STIX2 package. The two solutions I found were (having them in the preamble):

Option 1: If you need to change just this one symbol:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathbbE}{\mathord}{AMSb}{"45}
\newcommand{\ex}{\mathbbE}
```

Option 2: If you anticipate needing to replace more symbols:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathams}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\ex}{\mathams{E}}
```

With either way you can have whatever font you want but ensure to have the desired expected value sign.

For instance (need to be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, not PDFLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math, fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathams}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\ex}{\mathams{E}}
\newcommand{\var}{\mathams{V}}
\begin{document}
\noindent STIX2 looking symbols:
\[\mathbb{E}, \mathbb{V}\]
AMS looking symbols:
\[\ex, \var\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show compilable TeX code for a fast proof of your solution(s)? And can you add an screenshot of the results?