# How can I get a list of all \fontfamily{...}\fontseries{...} combinations?

Tags: fonts, distributions

Someone just suggested to me in the context of [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378621/5640) to consider one or two `\fontfamily{...}\fontseries{...}` combinations; but I'm not too keen on those options. How can I check *all* such combinations installed/available on my system?

**Note:** I'd be ok with doing this outside of LaTeX, e.g. from the shell or even using some TeX-distribution-specific mechanism (I use TeXLive) - if there's no better option.

Comment: With a lot work. Every font can have different valid combinations.

Comment: You really can't. Apart from a small set of accepted conventions, such as `n` `it` `sl` `sc` `m` `b` `bx`, the code are essentially arbitrary. There are scores of `\fontfamily` designations.

Comment: @egreg: See edit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: But people package these fonts into the TeX distribution. Surely there's some catalog, some convention for filenames, whatever.

Comment: A rough count shows that the number of `.fd` files in my current TeX Live is 3245. There are many “duplicates”, because there are several encodings for each family. I get 555 `.fd` files for the T1 encoding.

Comment: @egreg: Can I translate `.fd` filenames into (family, series) tuples?

Comment: @einpoklum You can see a typical `.fd` file in my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Crosslink to related questions: [berry - Is there a list available for all TeX fonts? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/is-there-a-list-available-for-all-tex-fonts), [conditionals - How can I test for the current font? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/how-can-i-test-for-the-current-font)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all possible values, but you can get an overview about the most common options if mouse hovering the command in question in `texstudio`:

*(this does not check if all the fonts are installed on your system and which of the weights they actually have)*

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do I know which family has which combinations of weight and condensation? Specifically, the [Tug.DK site](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) doesn't seem to list these combinations, at least [not for typewriter fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html)

Comment: @einpoklum does http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf, Table 3 help?

Comment: @einpoklum Or for a specific font, have a look at the available files - for example https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/anonymouspro/truetype is available in the 4 weights indicated by the file names.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. If a list of the available files can give me information, wouldn't some shell script give me a list of everything installed on my system by looking at a bunch of folders?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , But where are serif, sans serif &monospaced?

Answer (score 8):

Font descriptions are usually kept in `.fd` files (but it's not mandatory, some packages may define the fonts directly in the `.sty` file).

The shell command

```
fd '^[tT]1.*\.fd$' /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex | wc -l
```

([`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) is a script providing a simpler interface than `find`) returns 555.

So there are 555 font families supporting the T1 encoding (and 502 for the OT1 encoding, with a similar command line).

Now your task is to look inside each `.fd` file you're interested in and extract the information related to the shape and series provided in the font family. Just for example, `T1Roboto-LF.fd` contains

```
%% Generated by autoinst on 2015/09/15
%%
\ProvidesFile{T1Roboto-LF.fd}
    [2015/09/15 (autoinst)  Font definitions for T1/Roboto-LF.]

\expandafter\ifx\csname Roboto@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\Roboto@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\Roboto@@scale{s*[\csname Roboto@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{Roboto-LF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Light-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Light-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-LightItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-LightItalic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/l/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/l/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Black-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Black-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-BlackItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-BlackItalic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/k/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{k}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/k/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Bold-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Bold-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-BoldItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-BoldItalic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Medium-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Medium-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-MediumItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-MediumItalic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/mb/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{mb}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/mb/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Regular-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Regular-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Italic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Italic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/m/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{m}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/m/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{sc}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Thin-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{n}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-Thin-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{it}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-ThinItalic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{scit}{
      <-> \Roboto@@scale Roboto-ThinItalic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/t/scit
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{t}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/t/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/sl
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/scsl
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{sc}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/sc
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{n}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/n
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{it}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Roboto-LF}{bx}{scit}{
      <-> ssub * Roboto-LF/b/scit
}{}

\endinput
```

which says the font provides the series

- `l` (light)
- `k` (black)
- `b` (bold)
- `mb` (medium bold)
- `m` (medium or regular)
- `t` (thin)

and defines `bx` as an alias for `b`.

The descriptors, apart from `m` and `b` are essentially arbitrary strings. The LaTeX Font Guide (`texdoc fntguide`) lists just a few “common” values. What a font package calls `k` might be very different from another one.

Answer (score 2):

This website might help. Useful to check fonts available.

https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

Answer (score 0):

The list is bigger even that that. It is open-ended.
The answer is x.

Now that xelatex and lualatex can access system fonts, not just tex/latex ones, the list has grown greatly.

Further,

Suppose I use the `fontspec` package and define a font family `\setromanfont{Noto Serif}[` and then name one of its series `仢ul` and assign an unrelated font face to that series, `FontFace={仢ul}{n}{Font=SimSun},` and I do that multiple times,

and have 
`\DeclareRobustCommand{\仢ulseries}{\fontseries{仢ul}\selectfont}`

and

`\DeclareTextFontCommand{\仢textul}{\仢ulseries}`

and then call the series with

`\仢textul{\sampletext} {\仢ulseries \sampletext}`

where `\sampletext` is defined as

`\newcommand\sampletext{了亶他件}`

and I do that for as many series (and shapes) as I want or need,

then I get

[image: myseries]

The list would be limited by system constraints, though.