# How to install webomints in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: fonts, packages, installing-fonts

I need the webomint font, but when I try to compile a document with it I get the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `webomints.sty' not
>   found.

I know that it means that LaTeX doesn't find the package, so I looked around and I found out that some fonts must be installed separately and that webomints is one of them. I tried to install them in several ways, none of which worked for me, so I tried to compile a minimal document to be sure that the problem wasn't due to other packages doing strange interactions, but nothing changed.

I tried to install the package in the following ways:

### Through `getnonfreefonts`

I installed `getnonfreefonts` and run `sudo getnonfreefonts --sys --all` and rebooted the computer but pdflatex still gave me the error. When I run `sudo getnonfreefonts --sys --lsfonts` I get the following output, so I suppose that the package is installed:

```
me@mypc:~$ sudo getnonfreefonts --sys --lsfonts
--2019-09-01 15:24:05--  https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl
Risoluzione di www.tug.org (www.tug.org)... 91.121.174.77
Connessione a www.tug.org (www.tug.org)|91.121.174.77|:443... connesso.
[...]
webomints      Webomints (Galapagos Design Group)                   [installed]
```

### Through "manual way"

I tried to follow [the *Installation instructions* provided by CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/webomints), but I couldn't find the directory fonts/tfm/public/misc

### Other ways

I also followed suggestions from other Q&A posts, both from Stack Exchange and other websites, none of which worked for me. I'd like to add some links but I don't remember them; however, I just asked to Google something like "LaTeX install webomints" and so on.

---

I am working in Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Digo): an OS specific answer, if necessary, would be appreciated. I have full root access, so I can do everything I have to do to make the stuff work.

Please else consider that I am quite new to both Ubuntu and LaTeX.

---

### Update

@daleif
These is exactly what I get when I launch the commands you asked for (except for user an pc names, which I obscured):

```
me@mypc:~$ kpsewhich article.cls
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
me@mypc:~$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password di me: 
me@mypc:~$ locate webomints.sty
me@mypc:~$
```

`locate webomints.sty` does not output anything, which I suppose is not a good news...

I use TeX Live, which I installed following [the instructions from tug.org](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and acquiring it "over the internet" (using the net install).

Comment: From a terminal can you tell us what output `kpsewhich article.cls`  gives? Also with `locate webomints.sty` (the latter might need `sudo updatedb`) first. The first command we use to get a little information about your latex system. The latter a little information about where webomints may have gone. You never told us what latex you actually have installed. Is it a latex from Ubuntu or something else. I use something else and I actually don't know what happens if you use getnonfreefonts on an Ubuntu latex (there might be small differences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webomints` package does not include a `sty` file, as can bee seen on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/webomints). Instead you can look at the provided sample files for inspiration. In essence you only have to state that you want to use the appropriate font. And  the call to `getnonfreefonts` was (most likely) sufficient to get that going:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n} ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOPQRST UVWXYZ}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you very much and sorry for my mistake. May you also explain me the `\usefont` syntax, please?

Comment: @Ntakwetet See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338067/140850 for an explanation of `\usefont` and fonts in general.