# Why does LaTeX trigger a font warning when I don't even use that font and how can I trace it down to an input file?

Tags: debugging

My first question is, when exactly does LaTeX trigger a font warning? I suspect, it is in the moment when I request a font through `\sffamily` or `\selectfont`, correct?

This is why

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\fontseries{book}\selectfont \fontseries{m}\selectfont Test
\end{document}
```

results in

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/book/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.
```

even though I need no single glyph of the `book` series I requested.

---

So with that knowledge my issue is, that in my document, I get a spurious font warning from the `\tableofcontents`, because `bx` series is not available in my loaded `\sfdefault` font and replaced with `m` instead. But no text element is typeset in that font, which is why I don't know where to start to look for it, but I suspect a definition I don't even use tries to select `bx`.

What way can you propose me to trace down where `bx` is requested and then not used? So this is not about only this problem, but more a question about a debugging technique. Is it e.g. possible to hook to `\selectfont` and let it print, when it was called and from which file?

Thanks for your help and hints and please let me know, if I need to clarify further.

---

**Addition to clarify**

Thank you very much for your comments so far. While I appreciate, that you want to look into my specific issue here, I am really more eager to learn, how to debug myself. So here is a MWE that illustrates the issue a bit better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mycommand.tex}
\newcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{{\fontseries{seriesthatdoesnotexist}\selectfont \fontseries{m}\selectfont #1}}
\end{filecontents}

\input{mycommand.tex}

\begin{document}
    \MyCommand{Test}
\end{document}
```

Imagine `mycommand.tex` is not that obviously laoded, but is in the documentclass, a package or wherever. But when you see the font warning in the log, it reads:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/seriesthatdoesnotexist/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

From other programming or scripting languages I am used to have a debugger that can step through my code, or set breakpoints, as well as the possibility to see a trace of all calls that have been made before.

In this case LaTeX leaves me with an issue in line 11, that I cannot understand, if I don't know where and how `\MyCommand` has been defined.

Is it actually possible to get a trace to the place of the command that actually caused the issue or the place where a command was defined? So in this case, is there a way to lead me to `mycommand.tex`?

I hope this addition clarifies, what I am looking for, which is a debugging technique and not a solution for the font substitution problem.

---

A MWE that illustrates the problem in the real world:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
%%%%\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont} %solves the issue
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\Large\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

It took me some more time, but here is a MWE in the real world. The `chapter` font is normally `\sffamily\bfseries`, but even if you overwrite it, it is still selected, because the komafont `disposition` is used before. Now the line `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}` fixes the issue, but how can this be traced and debugged, without this knowledge?

Comment: Warnings tel you that font series "book" doesn't exist. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68745/possible-values-for-fontseries-and-fontshape

Comment: @Zarko this was on purpose, I could write `foo` or `doesnotexist`. What I wanted to illustrate is, that loading a font already results in a font warning, even though it is not used. In my specific document I am looking for the location where this warning is thrown, but I can only trace it down to the `\tableofcontents` command, this is why I suspect, that my document class selects a font shape through `\selectfont` and then loads another one before actually writing something.

Comment: You are requesting a font combination that doesn't exist; the warning is issued at font selection time: it's not possible to wait until a character is typeset.. Possibly the warning might say “selecting” instead of “using”, but usually people uses the font they tried to select. Can you please show a short example of code that triggers the warning you're receiving?

Comment: Have you seen the site guidelines for preparing a MWE (minimal working example): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that ?  These guidelines are also good for a debugging technique.  In summary: gradually remove document content, then packages, or alternatively start from an empty document and gradually add things back in; and in either case, note at what stage the error disappears/reappears, and try to cut things down to a minimal example document triggering the error.

Comment: @egreg thanks for this information, this confirms my analysis from above. If it would be that simple in this case, I would have brought up the actual problem in a MWE. But I am still looking for a way to achieve this and I am in general more interested in a general debugging approach for LaTeX similar to other languages.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine my first MWE triggers the warning already, but is of course easy to debug. However I added two more MWEs, including solutions (because I know the issue behind the scenes), but again I would like to learn the debugging technique, this is why I opened this question.

Comment: @TobiBS You can't ask TeX where a command was defined: the information is not stored anyway, for the simple reason that a command can be redefined everywhere, including the command itself: with `\def\foo{\def\foo{something else}}`, the redefinition would happen when `\foo` is first called.