# Combining Typefaces

Tags: fonts, fontspec, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing font for bold small caps (or any other particular family+series+shape combination)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22240/choosing-font-for-bold-small-caps-or-any-other-particular-familyseriesshape-co)

I am using Aldus obtained from Adobe and installed using this method (after converting to T1 fonts): http://ftp.sun.ac.za/ftp/CTAN/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/pas.txt

Using the font works fine, except Aldus does not contain a bold face and I would like LaTeX to select the bold face from Palatino, is there an easy way to do this?

**EDIT:** I wanted to try something along the lines of [Choosing font for bold small caps (or any other particular family+series+shape combination)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22240/choosing-font-for-bold-small-caps-or-any-other-particular-familyseriesshape-co) , but doing the following does not work:

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pasj}{bx}{n} { <-> ssub * ppl/bx/n }{}
```

I guess I might be a bit naive and do not understand exactly how `\DeclareFontShape` works. Does there have to be a package 'pasj' for this to work? At the moment I just include the font as:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pasj}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)
This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22240/choosing-font-for-bold-small-caps-or-any-other-particular-familyseriesshape-co. Please take a look at it as the answer there might help you. If it does, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If it doesn't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Using LuaTeX or XeTeX

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldFont = PalatinoLTStd-Medium, 
BoldItalicFont = PalatinoLTStd-MediumItalic]{Aldus LT Std}
```

I think the bold face of Palatino is too bold for Aldus, the Medium weight is better:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Whereas the original Aldus font, created by Hermann Zapf in 1954, indeed only has roman (upright) and italic shapes, there is now the 'Aldus Nova' font, created by Akira Kobayashi and Hermann Zapf in 2005, that comes in the "standard" four categories (roman, italic, bold, and bold&italic). Buying "just" the bold font would set you back $79; see http://www.linotype.com/109957/Aldusnova-family.html. (I have no financial interest in the Linotype company, by the way!)

On the compatibility of Aldus and Palatino (also created by Hermann Zapf): I once read (can't remember where) that Zapf initially considered Palatino to be more of a titling font (i.e., best when used at larger font sizes) whereas Aldus was, in his opinion, better at smaller font sizes. I suppose that this opinion didn't exactly harm Palatino's success in the market for book fonts over the past 50 years, did it! Still, if you can stay with either all-Aldus or all-Palatino, you're probably better off that way.

Addendum:

If you're going to mix Aldus and Palatino, you must do something about their (slightly) different x-heights; more precisely, you should reduce the scale of the Palatino fonts appropriately. To achieve this without having to work too much on converting yet another font, I think you're best off switching from pdflatex to xelatex -- trust me, the learning curve isn't steep at all -- and issue the following commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
[
Scale      = MatchUppercase,
BoldFont   = {Palatino Bold}, 
BoldItalicFont = {Palatino Bold Italic} %% optional
]
{Aldus LT Std Roman}
```

The precise names of the Palatino fonts will vary depending on the source.

Comment: Zapf did said that! However the inclusion of Palatino as one of the 35 PS base fonts, and some copycat like those from Micr@soft, made it extremely popular.

Comment: I believe also that Palatino as it was originally drawn was somewhat different than the digital ones we see now — it wouldn't surprise me to learn that Zapf intentionally made Palatino a little more text-like over time.

Comment: I want to use Palatino for chapter and section names, which will be typeset at larger font sizes. Buying a bold face for $80 is a bit steep for me, but I guess that would be the "nicest" way to do this.

Comment: On font selection: Your command \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pasj} needs to be followed by \selectfont. On "mixing" the two fonts: if the bold face will be used only in captions of chapters and sections, I think that the use of Palatino would be just fine.

Comment: I think I am missing something, if I do \selectfont after \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pasj}, how do I force the substitution pasj/bx/n -> ppl/bx/n  ? I get the following error if I do it like in my original question: Font family `T1+pasj' unknown.

Comment: Karl: Please see the additional thoughts left in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I will check out XeTeX...but I rely heavily on TikZ and I quite like the microtyping feature in pdflatex. Guess one cannot always have everything.

Comment: One more thing: Until Sept 6, if you purchase and download any fonts (including Aldus nova fonts!) from fonts.com and apply the coupon code **94DCF**, you get a 20% discount off the list price of any font. :-)

Comment: Karl: I learned a couple of days ago that the latest version of microtype (2.5) supports XeTeX (and luatex). It's not yet on the CTAN, but you may find it online at http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=2131818604/action=view/id=569. Given that you were holding off on using xelatex because of lack of compatibility with microtype, this may be especially welcome news for you.