# Colored Small Caps

Tags: fonts, color, small-caps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face)

I'm trying to get some bold, colored, small-cap text. I've tried different variations, including:

```
{\bf \textcolor{blue}{\textsc{text}}}
```

and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is a font problem. You don't have a font loaded that supports bold caps.

Comment: You need to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{xcolor}` and then `\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries\textsc{text}}`. Don't use the deprecated `\bf`. For more on this, see [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, ...) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you have bold caps in your font avaiable. Don't use `\bf` and so on because they overwrite each other. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\textsc{bold small blue caps}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sry werner, I was typing when you posted the same solution as comment...