# Why won't this header have proper small caps?

Tags: fonts

If I'm correct, small caps means if I had a word like, say, WORD, the W would be bigger than the other letters slightly, right?

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\newcommand{\header}[1]{
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.5in}{-0.5in}
        \bf\scshape\textsc{#1} \\
    \lineover
    \end{changemargin}
}
```

However, it won't display. It's just bolded, non-caps for the headers.

Word is **Word**.

The differences between `\sc`, `\scshape` and `textsc` is confusing me too.

Answer (score 8):

No in a small caps (or more accurately caps and small caps) the font has upper and lower case letters but the letter form of the lower case letters are (smaller) capitals. So `WORD` would look like WORD  but Word would look like WORD in which the W was larger than ORD.

However not all font families are available in small caps shape so in some case LaTeX will substitute the font requested (you get a warning about that in the log file).

```
\bf\scshape\textsc{#1}
```

`\bf` is a deprecated command (not defined in the core LaTeX format) which would be better written as `\normalfont\bfseries` that sets the current font to bold for the rest of the current scope.  `\scshape` then requests that the shape is changed to small caps (still bold) then `\textsc{...}` asks for small caps again. the `\text...` forms limit the scope of the font change to their argument.  so `\bfseries` makes everything bold until the next `}` or `\end{___}`  whereas `\textbf{word}` just makes **word** bold.

In article class, with the default `cm` fonts

```
 \bf\scshape\textsc{word}
```

produces a log of

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 17.
```

Which tells you that bold extended **bx** small caps **sc** is not available in the 7bit **OT1** Computer Modern Roman **cmr** family and that normal **n** shape has been substituted.

Try it without the bold and you will get small caps.

Answer (score 2):

For changing the font stype, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/21591).

So if I use

```
\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.5in}{-0.5in}%
        \textsc{#1} \\
     \lineover
    \end{changemargin}%
}
...
\header{Word}
```

I get *Word* in small caps. However, not all fonts provide a small caps variant, please look out for warnings when you compile.