# How to further capitalize the First letter of a word already in block?

Tags: capitalization

What I am wishing for is something like the capitalization of word in block in section headings.

[image]

How may I have it in normal text mode?

e.g.

> I want to further capitalize the `B` in `BLOCK`.

Comment: do you mean something like, `\textsc{Block}`?

Comment: @cmhughes  exactly! Thanks a lot! It is really difficult to search for this.

Comment: I agree, it can be tough to search for this :) Could we call it a duplicate of [Small Caps and Bold Face](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411)

Comment: @cmhughes Oh, now I know it is techinically called "bold face"! But for the persons who do not how to technically coin the word, they may still fail to find that question in Google search. :)

Comment: This style is called __small caps__ (“Kapitälchen” in German) and _not_ bold face!

Comment: @Tobi  Also, danke shoen fuer die Information!