# break lines in latex tabular

Tags: tables

I would like to get the "Journal 2 name line 1" text to line up with the first line in the 2nd column.  In my code, the text in line 2 of the first column, lines up with the line 1 of the 2nd column:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
\textsc{Journal 1}
& Article 1 -- 2013\\
& \\
& Article 2 -- 2005\\
& \\
\textsc{Journal 2 name line 1} \\
\textsc{Journal 2 name line2}& Name of Journal 2 article 1 \\
& article 2 continued -- 2003 \\
& \\
& Article 2 name line 1\\
& Article 2 name line2 -- 2001\\

\end{tabular}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but perhaps you're after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
  \textsc{Journal 1}
  & Article 1 -- 2013\\
  & \\
  & Article 2 -- 2005\\
  & \\
  \textsc{Journal 2 name line 1} & Article 1 line 1 \\
  \textsc{Journal 2 name line 2} & Article 1 line 2 -- 2003 \\
  & \\
  & Article 2 name line 1\\
  & Article 2 name line 2 -- 2001\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Not that there are no **bold** small caps. See [Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/5764).