# csvsimple inside tabular environment, but csv data includes LaTeX arrays/tables/aligned etc

Tags: tables, arrays, csv, csvsimple

I am trying to import a csv using `csvsimple`, and I have already overcome the challenge of the csv delimiter (by adding curly braces around every field), but I am now stuck with a admittedly weird problem. I would explain in more detail, but a simplified example shows this issue nicely enough.

I've adapted the example information from an answer [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238283), but separated the csv data to a standalone file.

let `jobname.csv` be:

```
11.0; 12.3; $x^2$; seven$
1.2; 33.11; five; six
```

let our .tex file be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\midrule
\csvreader[
  separator=semicolon,
  no head,
  late after line=\\,
]{jobname.csv}{}{%
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv
}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

When I run this everything is fine.

**The issue happens when I include an array or some similar environment that uses `&` and `\\`.**

Change contents of `jobname.csv` to:

```
11.0; 12.3; $x^2$; \begin{array}{cc}2 & 4 \\ 6 & 8\end{array}
1.2; 33.11; five; six
```

When I run this, everything is **not fine**. From what I can tell, the `\\` causes the problem, and then TeX tries to interpret the `&` as part of the tabular environment.

I understand this is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164311/break-lines-in-latex-tabular), but I fear automating the conversion of my csv data to fit this data would be quite difficult, since my actual project already contains some 300 cells of LaTeX snippets.

Comment: Through TeX, the only attmept you can make is to read each cell verbatim. The (unmaintained!!) `tabu` package might be able to. Otherwise, you can try to look some ConTeXt magic or preprocess the file with different script language and result put back to TeX.

Comment: Thanks Tomáš. I figured as much, but I was hopeful this package would save me from more writing more python early in my project. I understand a proper scripting language is probably much more effective than a LaTeX package, but I preferred the simplicity of the csvsimple package while setting up my templates.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `$`'s around `array` environment in `jobname.csv` file:

```
11.0; 12.3; $x^2$; $\begin{array}{cc}2 & 4 \\ 6 & 8\end{array}$
1.2; 33.11; five; six
```

With `csvsimple-l3` (2.1.0 2021-07-06) you can get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  tabular=cccc,
  table head=\toprule 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \midrule,
  separator=semicolon,
  no head,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
]{jobname.csv}{}{%
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\csvcoliv}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach using `readarray`.

```
%dbA
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{databaseA.csv}
11.0; 12.3; $x^2$; $\begin{array}{cc}2 & 4 \\ 6 & 8\end{array}$
1.2; 33.11; five; six
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2021-08-08]
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{;}
\readdef{databaseA.csv}\dbA
\readarray\dbA\arrayA[-,\ncols]

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
\typesetarray\arrayA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code in a new file in overleaf. When I try compiling the contents of the file there are 3 errors reported: Command typesetrowsepchar undefined, Command typesetcolsepchar undefined, and Undefined control sequence. for <recently read> \typesetarray 
                              
l.18 \typesetarray
                  \arrayA\\ 
Am I missing anything in terms of the code e.g. what's the significance of the [2021-08-08]? or do I need to use a particular latex compiler. I ask as your approach may well help me process gnarly contents of csv files. Thx

Comment: @JulianHarty You need to get the latest version of the package, found at https://ctan.org/pkg/readarray.  If you can't install it in your system, then placing `readarray.sty` in your working directory should temporarily suffice.  The date you asked about is a "required" package date.  If you are using an older version, a warning will appear in your log file.