# Small caps and bold styles in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, bold, small-caps

I am trying to use small caps and boldface styles together in beamer but it is not producing the desired output. How is possible to use both styles without changing too much the default beamer's font?

By the way, I tried the answers given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face) for a similar question but they only seem to work within the `article` class.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Needed encodings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textbf{\textsc{Test}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And its output:[image]

Comment: Note that extensive use of small-caps in a presentation is likely not a good idea as it will make it more difficult to read. If you are using them just for abbreviations or something, that is probably fine. But I wouldn't use them for titles etc.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr. Indeed I was thinking of using it for part titles, so I will take your advice. Nevertheless, I am still interested in an answer.

Comment: Yes, the answer has independent interest since bold small caps, while not traditional, may be useful in other documents (e.g. when there are not screen-reading issues involved).

Answer (score 3):

The sans-serif default font does not have small capitals.

You can use a different font, eg [KP Sans-Serif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kpsans/). With `\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}` in the preambule it produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Benoa441, I see that this font allows to do what I want to. The bad part is that I find its math font less appealing than the sans-serif one (the same also for plain text, but I guess I could get used in this case).

Comment: How would one do this for serif?

Comment: You can use `{\rmfamily{\textbf{\textsc{Test}}}`, but it's not the clever method if you had lot of text. In this case, you can prefer `\usefonttheme{serif}` and `\textbf{\textsc{Test}}`