# Small Capitals in \contentsname and \addcontentsline

Tags: small-caps

How can I use small capitals to write the `TABLE`s in `\contentsname` and `\addcontentsline`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE of contents}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE of contents}
\chapter{text}
\section{text}
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, `\textsc{Table}` should give the desired result... but unfortunately it doesn't.

That's discernible from this warning
[image: warning]
where the default font (CMR) seems to miss the `sc` shape.

You may use the `times` package (or `fourier`, `palatino`, `bookman`, ...)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{times}   %% or use {fourier} {palatino} {bookman} ...

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textsc{Table} of contents}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textsc{Table} of contents}
\chapter{text}
\section{text}
text
\end{document}
```

to get this kind of results, which I hope, is close to what you want :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but can I use the small capitals with the default font?

Comment: The following may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334368/how-te-get-bold-small-caps-with-latin-modern-or-computer-modern

Comment: Inserting ```\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}``` enables this. Thanks.