# format line spacing and abtract

Tags: formatting, line-spacing, abstract

[image]

How do i remove the space infront of the 'Lorem' and how do i set the linespacing to 6pt after abstract ?

Requirements:

- Abstract heading
- Alignment : left
- Size : 13pt , bold italic Times New Roman , Small caps
- Paragraph line spacing : 6 pt

Eg. After the Abstract i need include 6 pt of line spacing and then continue to the abstract content.

This is the requirement i want, and i not sure how to set for the line spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=30mm,
    top=30mm,
    right=30mm,
    bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontsize{13}{16}\scshape\itshape\bfseries\selectfont\parskip6pt}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\itshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\noindent \lipsum[1]` to remove the space before Lorem.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And how about the line spacing? Is that using parskip6pt for line spacing just like what written in my code?

Comment: Or the setting is already default Eg. after /title then the paragraph line spacing is auto 24pt ?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to change the `\parskip`parameter, which governs the amount of white space *between* paragraphs, for the `abstract` environment: Abstracts usually consist of a single (and hopefully brief) paragraph, right?

Comment: Abstract heading Left 13 pt. bold italic TNR, small caps 6 pt. line sp.
Abstract text Justify 10 pt. italic TNR 12 pt. line sp. This is the requirement i want, and i not sure how to set for the line spacing.

Comment: i edited my post, included packages. Please tell me what is the problem and i also cannot use the bold,small caps and italic together to format my text. ty

Comment: I would not use italic bold scshape, as times new roman is not shipped with this fontshape. I don't think many fonts support this. Simulating it is not a good idea, it would look terrible.

Comment: See this post : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face#27413 For the rest, I think you could use something like `\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontsize{13}{16}\scshape\slshape \parskip6pt}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\itshape\noindent\ignorespaces}`

Comment: Not really work, if i put bold for the text. It can either in italic with small caps or only bold...

Comment: yes, because that font feature doesn't exist, and shouldn't be simulated. It is of course hackable, but would look terrible. And no, MS Word doesn't make it look good either, it fakes it too. And do you really want bold italic scshape? Even if the font-feature did exist, and was handcrafted to still look good, what would the signaling effect be? I suggest changing it to something that actually exists.

Comment: Is the assignment to produce the required formatting? Or is the assignment something else? I've never heard of anybody requiring bold, italic and small-caps all at once. Italic small-caps are quite rare. Bold small-caps are not common either. (Oblique is not the same as italic, of course. `\slshape` gives you oblique, which might be what Word tells you is italic, but isn't.)

Comment: yeah, my assignment format is similar to this docs link. I have no idea how to format it with latex. http://www.glyndwr.ac.uk/computing/research/ita05/formatguide.doc

Comment: Your code cannot, of course, be compiled as it stands as it is radically incomplete. Nonetheless, it makes no sense to load the mix of packages you are using. Loading `lmodern`, `mathptmx` and `kpfonts` is probably pointless if you then load `fontspec`. You almost certainly do not want to load `fontenc` since you are using `fontspec`. You do not want to load `slantsc` or `bold-extra` if using `fontspec`.

Comment: But is the assignment to do the formatting? Or is the assignment something else? Few people here are going to rush to download a DOC.

Comment: If the requirements will make your document look terrible anyway, why not just use Word or LibreOffice or whatever? It isn't clear that there's much to be gained by making LaTeX create ugly results, because it is surprisingly difficult to get TeX to mess things up badly enough to pass as Word. `philosophy.sty` may be of help, though. (Search for it.) If it just needs to look awful, it might work. However, TNR just doesn't have the combination of weight and shape. (And, yes, you can fake it. But doing so is evil.)

Comment: Just want to get extra mark for it. No matter how also need to use latex to generate it ;(

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=30mm,
    top=30mm,
    right=30mm,
    bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontsize{13}{16}\scshape\itshape\bfseries\selectfont\parskip6pt}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\itshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\vspace*{6pt}
\noindent \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]