# Small caps in section/chapter title

Tags: fonts, sectioning, small-caps

I am using `report` document class, and want to use small caps in titles of chapters, sections... if I write `\section{\textsc{Lorem Ipsum}}` it will be lowercase, not small caps.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\textsc{Lorem Ipsum}}

Dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal example (i.e. the shortest possible compilable document showing this effect)? It all depends on the `documentclass` and the loaded packages.

Comment: @riddleculous ok, done.

Comment: `\chapter{{\sc Lorem Ipsum}}` works though looks ugly because it overrides the bold face. The problem here is that the standard font doesn't support small caps in bold and is thus replaced by the standard font. If you want to fix this, use another font. Maye [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face) helps.

Comment: If you want all titles to be in small caps, the easiest way is to do `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\allsectionsfont{\scshape}`.

Comment: If I want to use small caps but in bold for sections, is there any way around it?