# Automatic Chapter or Section Title in Bold face and Small Caps

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec, bold, small-caps

I have a very basic question that is basically a follow-up of [this old one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face).

How can I have small caps that are boldface in the title of a chapter or a section?

Below a MWE.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\rmfamily % To load Latin Modern Roman and enable the following NFSS declarations.
% Declare that Latin Modern Roman (lmr) should take
% its bold (b) and bold extended (bx) weight, and small capital (sc) shape, 
% from the corresponding Computer Modern Roman (cmr) font, for the T1 font encoding.
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}


%
\usepackage{titlesec}


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-21\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries\sc  \thechapter.\quad #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\huge\bfseries\sc}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

In particular, I am currently using the answer provided by user @Blaisorblade from the link above, along with titlesec, but nothing really happens: as it can be noted, the title of chapter is in small caps, but is not bold face and the same applies to the TOC entry.

Any feedback will be most welcome!

Comment: Please note that questions on tex.se should be self-sustained and not require readers to follow links, then search for the answer you might mean and construct a test document themselves.

Comment: If you want all titles to be in small caps, the easiest way is to do \usepackage{sectsty} and \allsectionsfont{\scshape}. This answer is given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357933/small-caps-in-section-chapter-title).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the point: MWE provided.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak thanks for the feedback. However, my problem is not with small caps, but with small caps along with bold face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already told [in Will's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27413/277964) to the question vou've linked, you should not use `\sc`, because this deprecated font command does also deactivate the previous `\bfseries`. Use `\scshape` instead:

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Note: Not needed since LaTeX 2018/04/01.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\rmfamily % To load Latin Modern Roman and enable the following NFSS declarations.
% Declare that Latin Modern Roman (lmr) should take
% its bold (b) and bold extended (bx) weight, and small capital (sc) shape, 
% from the corresponding Computer Modern Roman (cmr) font, for the T1 font encoding.
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}

%
\usepackage{titlesec}% Note: Loaded but currently not used.


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{% Note: Instead of redefining \@makechapterhead, you could use the already loaded titlesec.
  \vspace*{-21\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries\scshape  \thechapter.\quad #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\usepackage{tocloft}% Note: Instead of using tocloft, you could also redefine \@makeschapterhead similar to your redefinition of \@makechapterhead.
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\huge\bfseries\scshape}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot: great!

Comment: btw, somewhat related: do you have any idea why I have no control at all over the title of the reference chapter? Neither I can move it, nor it shows like all the others.

Comment: @Kolmin Redefining `\@makechapterhead` changes only numbered chapters (`\chapter{…}`) but not the not numbered chapters (`\chapter*`). Because of this, you need `tocloft` in your example to also change the heading of `\tableofcontents`. See my comments about how to change this.