# Undefined font shape with lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, latin-modern

I know that this is a quite common question, but looking for many threads about undefined font shape I didn't find any solution...

When I compile my document with `lualatex` I get 5 different warnings related to undefined font shapes substituted.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 14.
--
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line
--
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line
--
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/n' instead on input lin
--
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/cmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 25.
--
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Below is the minimal working example with my five warnings. Actually, I think there are 3 different error sources:

- a first one related to `lmodern` package: I believed that `lmr` includes maaaaany font shapes, in particular, all variations with `lf/md/bf` and `up/it/sl/sc` shapes ;
- the second one related to the way I define the font used for foreign language (maybe it's not the right place for this problem) ;
- a third one related to the use of `cmr` by the gnuplot cairolatex output.

Well, I'm interested in any idea to solve any of these problems.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Font packages
\usepackage{lmodern} % serif

% Define language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{french}
\setotherlanguage[]{english}
% Define english font
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{lmroman12-italic.otf} % Use italic font for foreign language

\begin{document}
  \textsc{\textbf{TU/lmr/bx/sc $\to$ TU/lmr/bx/n}}

  \textenglish{\textbf{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/n $\to$ TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/n}}

  \textenglish{\textit{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/it $\to$ TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/n}}

  \textenglish{\textit{\textbf{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/it $\to$ TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/n}}}

  % Used including gnuplot cairolatex plots
  \begingroup
    \fontfamily{cmr}%
    \selectfont
    TU/cmr/m/n $\to$ TU/lmr/m/n
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, warnings about lmroman12-italic can be interpreted as 'don't pretend an italic font to be upright'. If you want any content of `\textenglish{}` to be italic by default, you could redefine `\textenglish` or patch it like the following: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \pretocmd{\textenglish}{\itshape}{}{}` instead. As for `cmr`, it haven't TU encoding support, heh.

Comment: Loading `lmodern` has no consequence on text fonts, because its settings would be overridden by `fontspec`; it still provides the setup for math fonts, though.

Comment: For italic english text redefinition of `\englishfont` is the recommended way for polyglossia. Btw I managed to do what I want with this definition:

    `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{lmroman10}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bolditalic,
    ItalicFont=*-regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bold,
    SmallCapsFont=lmromancaps10-oblique]`

Comment: `\let\englishfont\itshape`  should be enough! See my edited answer

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Related question: [fonts - Small Caps and Bold Face - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face/346627#346627)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `lmodern` along with `fontspec` does nothing relevant for text fonts, because all it does in this respect is

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
```

which is done anyway by `fontspec`. It can make sense to load it nonetheless, because it also sets Latin Modern as the math font.

The warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 17.
```

is due to Latin Modern lacking boldface small caps. The last warning is due to `cmr` lacking a font definition file for TU, so LaTeX does the default substitution in this case, that is, changing the family name to `\familydefault`, which expands to `\rmdefault` and so to `lmr`.

The other three warnings derive from you defining `\englishfont` in an incorrect way.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Font packages
\usepackage{lmodern} % serif

% Define language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{french}
\setotherlanguage[]{english}
% Define english font
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{lmroman}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  UprightFont=*10-italic,
  ItalicFont=*10-italic,
  BoldFont=*10-bolditalic,
  BoldItalicFont=*10-bolditalic,
  SmallCapsFont=*caps10-oblique,
]

\begin{document}

\textsc{\fontname\font}

\textsc{\textbf{\fontname\font}}

\textenglish{\textbf{\fontname\font}}

\textenglish{\textit{\fontname\font}}

\textenglish{\textit{\textbf{\fontname\font}}}

\textenglish{\textsc{\fontname\font}}

\end{document}
```

This will only raise one warning about the missing boldface small caps font.

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I was looking. To fix the `cmr` related error use `set terminal cairolatex font ','` in your gnuplot script to avoid any font definition in the resulting latex file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this definition:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
SmallCapsFont=Latin Modern Roman Caps,
SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters=SmallCaps},
ItalicFeatures  = {SmallCapsFont=LMRomanCaps10-Oblique}
]
% Define language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{french}
\setotherlanguage[]{english}
% Define english font
\let\englishfont\itshape

\begin{document}
    \textsc{\textbf{TU/lmr/bx/sc $\to$ TU/lmr/bx/n}}

    \textenglish{\textbf{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/n}}

    \textenglish{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/m/it}

    \textenglish{\textbf{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/it}}

    \textenglish{\textsc{TU/lmroman12-italic.otf(0)/bx/it}}

\end{document}
```

As far as I know there is no Bold Small Caps for Latin Modern

Comment: This only works if Latin Modern Roman is installed in the system font paths, doesn't it? Is there any way to rely on the `lmodern` package instead?

Comment: No, it works _always_ with LuaTeX!

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, but if it removes the warning, it doesn't generate bold small caps letters. No Bold Small Caps font are indeed available for Latin Modern and FakeBold are not supported by `lualatex`...

Comment: @Herbert can you update this to reflect the `\fontfamily{cmr}` part of the question also?

Comment: there is no need for cmr because the lmr is nearly the same and LAtin Modern is by loading fontspec the default font.