# How does LaTeX \scshape and \bfseries works with custom fonts?

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps

For a project, I am using Frutiger font files.

I have different files: regular, light, bold.

I have tried several things, but I am unable to get bold small caps characters. All of the solutions on [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face) seem to work on the default LaTeX font,  but not on mine.

What is annoying is the fact that Indesign or World easily deals with Small caps + bold. I am sure LaTeX can do as well !

So here is my question :
How does LaTeX responds to `\scshape` and `\bfseries` commands? Is there a "built-in" response turning your font to bold or is LaTeX always using a specific font file?

If there is a "built in" answer, why isn't it working with small caps and bold fonts ?

If LaTeX uses font files everytime, how can I create my own file with small caps and bold characters ?

Thank  you all for your help   !

I am using `book` document class and  LuaLaTeX. Here is my code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{leading}
\leading{12.8pt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{BCBDC0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{emptypage}


\setmainfont{FrutigerLTStd-Roman.otf}

\newfontfamily{\frutL}{FrutigerLTStd-Light.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutB}{FrutigerLTStd-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutR}{FrutigerLTStd-Roman.otf}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{contour}


\begin{document}

\frutL Frutiger Light

\frutB Frutiger Bold

\frutR Frutiger Regular

\vspace{0.5cm}

\frutR{\textsc{\bfseries Frutiger Regular + small caps + bold}}

\frutR{\textbf{\scshape Frutiger Regular + small caps + bold}}

\end{document}
```

And  the result :
[image]

Here is the result I get on Indesign :

[image]

Comment: You can try using `fontspec` with `xelatex`.

Comment: We will need more details of how you are using the font: can you post an example?

Comment: Edited ! Sorry about this.

Comment: @Bernard, would it be possible to stick to LuaLaTeX ? I am using ```fontspec``` already.

Comment: fonts can handle this quite differently. You seem to have a special font for small caps, ACaslon-RegularSC.otf, do you have also a bold version here? Are you sure that word use a genuin bold small caps and not fake it e.g. by embolden the regular version font?

Comment: Yes, it should be working with LuaLaTeX too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your help. I  have edited my post : it was actually Frutiger and not Caslon, sorry about this. I have no small caps font file, and no small caps bold font file. I have edited my post with the result I get with Indesign, I does not look fake

Comment: @Bernard as you can see, I am already using ```fontspec``` but without success...

Comment: Remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that is completly wrong. Why are you defining all these families?

Comment: I have removed it, thanks ! It does not solved the issue but I guess my code is cleaner that way. Regarding the families, I am defining one for each file, isn't it what I am supposed to do ?

Comment: Examining the font at myfonts.com shows no small cap glyphs.  Other programs may fake them.

Comment: @Thérèse so the result I get on Indesign (see the pic on my post) is fake ? Then how can I fake it to look the same ?

Comment: No, you should use them to setup the main (or sans) font. Something like `\setmainfont{FrutigerLTStd-Roman.otf}[BoldFont=FrutigerLTStd-Bold.otf] ` etc, see the docu of fontspec.

Comment: There are other questions here about faking small caps, but I don’t recommend doing that; the results are not pleasing.

Comment: @Thérèse thank you, I have found something working well !