# How make section titles bold and small-caps

Tags: titlesec, bold, small-caps, section-titles

**Section titles should be bold+small-caps**
(but this code fail to do it)

```
       \usepackage{titlesec}
       \titleformat{\section}{\Large\sc\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
```

**Full code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sc\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 

\begin{document} 

\section{1 Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Please only make it work for section titles (not for subsection\subsubsection etc..)

Comment: For that, you need a font that has bold small caps.

Comment: @Bernard, which font support it?

Comment: I do not have a complete list, but, if I remember well, Latin Modern doesn't. Erewhon (which can work with fourier for maths) does have bold small caps. I'm not sure whether Computer Modern Unicode has, but you might test it.

Comment: also if you want font commands to combine don't use the old latex2.09 commands like `\sc` which do not combine, your usage `\sc\bfseries` works but looks odd  (and wouldn't work if `\bfseries` was first) `\scshape` is the standard command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

With  `pdflatex` look for a font using `fontenc` and having `\scshape` like

https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/newpx/

[image: bb]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % added <<<<
\usepackage{newpxtext}% added <<<<

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\scshape\bfseries\Large}{}{}{}[]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 

\begin{document} 
    
    \section{1 Introduction}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about  \usepackage{bold-extra} as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face — then we do not need fontenc?

Comment: @Ben It looks that in this simple example `\usepackage{bold-extra}` alone will do it.  Try it in your real document.