# Space between lines of large titles

Tags: spacing, titles, code, highlighting

I'm setting up a title sheet after the book cover and I'm having a hard time.

This title has very small line spacing.

I've tried using \setstretch{xx} but it didn't work.

What can I do?

The code is very simple:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % No headers
\newpage
%
% Folha de rosto

%
$\,$
%
\vfill \vfill
$\,$
%
\begin{center}
 \textsc{\Huge{Huge Title Very Important}}\\ %Título
\end{center}
%
%
$\,$
\vspace{0.25cm}

 ~\hrulefill ~\\

 \vspace{0.5cm}
 
\centering\textsc{\large{\textbf{Especial Colection}}}\\ %Coleção

 \vspace{1.5cm}
 $\,$

\vfill \vfill
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code?

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be a basic code.
send...

Comment: `Huge Title \\[10cm] Very Important`

Comment: you end the paragraph so are setting Huge text on the baseline for normalsize

Comment: @Symbol1 that's working around the erroneous input rather than fixing the error though.

Comment: Bravo! Thank u very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that `\Huge` doesn't have an accompanying `\par` that would set the appropriate baseline skip - necessary to allow for gaps between lines. Instead you should use a construction like this:

```
\begin{center}
  \scshape\Huge
  Huge Title Very Important
\end{center}
```

Here's a complete, minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
  \scshape\Huge
  Huge Title Very Important
\end{center}

\vspace{25mm}

\noindent~\hrulefill ~

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries\large Special Collection
\end{center}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Note that, by default, there is no **bold** small caps font. To achieve that, read [Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/5764).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much.