# Simplest way to reproduce this alignment?

Tags: tables, multicol, alignment, resume

I am looking to reproduce the column-like alignment in this document below:

[image]

Note that the header has both left-aligned and right-aligned text, and somehow the large text on the left takes up two lines worth on the right. The body seems to simply be columns with different widths, but otherwise pretty standard.

I thought this was going to be simple, but I've spent far too much time and I'm having quite a bit of trouble.

**Edit (8-15-2022)**: Since I've posted this, I've made some changes to the accepted answer and formed my own resume template. It doesn't include the images in the original example. Here it is:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-8pt}\scshape\bfseries\large
}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textopenbullet}

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeheading}[4]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & {\small#2}\\
    \textsl{\small#3} & {\small#4}
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Enable bold small caps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386933
\usepackage{lmodern} % Switch to Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\rmfamily
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0.25em}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}


\begin{document}

{\centering
  \textbox{\href{mailto:email@domain.com}{email@domain.com}}%
  \hfill {\huge \scshape {First Last}} \hfill%
  \textbox{\hfill \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/firstlast/}
    {linkedin.com/in/firstlast}}\par
}

\vspace{-0.5em}
\hrulefill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  {\color{Red} \textbf{\textsc{Education}}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.82\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  \vspace{-1pt}
  \resumeheading{Example College}{Graduation Date}{Degree}
    {Location}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.75em}
{\color{Red} \hrulefill}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  {\color{Red} \textbf{\textsc{Work\\Experience}}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.82\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  \resumeheading{Company 1}{Start Date -- End Date}{Job Title}{Location}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \resumeheading{Company 2}{Start Date -- End Date}{Job Title}{Location}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.75em}
{\color{Red} \hrulefill}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  {\color{Red} \textbf{\textsc{Leadership}}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.82\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{Organization 1} \textsl{\small Role} & {\small Start Date -- End Date}
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{Organization 2} \textsl{\small Role} & {\small Start Date -- End Date}
  \end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.75em}
{\color{Red} \hrulefill}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  {\color{Red} \textbf{\textsc{Skills}}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.82\textwidth}\vspace{-0.5em}%
  \textbf{Languages}: JavaScript/HTML/CSS, Java, Python, C++, OCaml, SQL

  \textbf{Frameworks}: Node.js
  
  \textbf{Tools}: Git, Docker, Kubernetes
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is not proffesional example and a bit hardcoding but it works:
[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
      top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}



\begin{document}

\noindent{\color{red} \rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm} }\\
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.15\textwidth}
  \textcolor{red}{Proffesional Expirience} 
  \end{minipage}
\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Facebook}\\
        \textit{Software Engineer}
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
      \textbf{August 2017 - present}\\
      \textit{Menlo Park, CA}
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent{\color{red} \rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm} }\\
  \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
  \vspace{-3.1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{amazon.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Amazon.com}\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item text text text text text text text text 
        text text text 
        \item text text text text text text text text 
        text text text text  
        \end{itemize}
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
      \textbf{August 2017 - present}\\
      \textit{Menlo Park, CA}
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```