# How to use \textsc{} in Section or Subsection?

Tags: section-titles

I am trying to add `\textsc{text}` in my subsection title

i tried  `\subsection{\textsc{Born-Oppenheimer} approximation}`

but no changement appeared, the text Born-Oppenheimer is not affected by the command `\textsc{}`. It is still in normal case.

note: i am using the book class: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}`

Do you know how i can fix this problem?

the document setup:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}[english]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=4.00cm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkbordercolor=red,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{chapter}
\stepcounter{section}
\subsection{\textsc{Born-Oppenheimer} approximation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [fonts - Small Caps and Bold Face - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face) except that... another possible workaround here is to make the text non-bold.

Comment: @user202729 - I agree. It's unfortunate that the OP has given no information about their document setup (other than tidbit that the `book` document class is in use).

Comment: Thanks for posting the full preamble. Now that all relevant information about your document is available, the easiest fix -- if you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document-- is to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27412/5001) to the query[Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/5001) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using a font -- possibly Computer Modern -- that doesn't provide a bold-smallcaps weight-shape glyph combination. If that's the case, you need to input

```
\subsection{\textsc{\textmd{Born-Oppenheimer}} approximation}
```

to get non-bold (aka "medium weight") smallcap letters for "Born-Oppenheimer".

To employ bold-smallcaps, you need to employ a font family that provides this particular combination. One such font family is Times (New) Roman.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\stepcounter{chapter} % just for this example
\stepcounter{section}

\subsection{\textsc{\textmd{Born-Oppenheimer}} approximation}
\subsection{\textsc{Born-Oppenheimer} approximation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works!