# About the command "\BibTeX"

Tags: bibtex, small-caps

I'm studying LaTeX now. From a book, I see **the symbol BiBTeX**

[image]

in a section title. Then I want to reproduce it.

```
%\usepackage{doc}
\section{\BibTeX}
\BibTeX
```

With above codes, I obtain the following results:

[image]

I don't know why *BibTeX* is not in **small capitals shape**.
The results are different between setion title and normal content.

---

From below comments, I think I have known some reasons for the problem. Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is an anwser.

**And I want to ask if my problem above is just caused by the requirement of both small caps and bold as the command `\BibTeX` is in the curly braces of `\section{}`**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: For PDFLaTeX [fonts - Small Caps and Bold Face - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face). For other engines...

Comment: Alright, for other engines I've left a comment under that question to list the available options.

Comment: Look in your `.log`. Do you notice any font-related warnings/substitutions?

Comment: @user202729 Get it! Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is an anwser.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for reminding. I browse `.log` and find the font-related warning.