# Font Problems using XeLaTEX

Tags: fonts, xetex, ebgaramond

Hello I'm using the following settings on my `standard.lco`, I have downloaded the font EB GARAMOND from [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/EB+Garamond). I downloaded the zip file and installed correctly on my windows 10.

A snip from my `standard.lco`

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont {EB Garamond}
\setsansfont {Gill Sans MT}

%set the font size and leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont}
```

When I call XeLaTeX with any text file, the command line says:

```
Font shape `EU1/EBGaramond(0)/bx/n' undefined
```

I think that I installed correctly the font, but I do not know how to fix it. Any suggestions? I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome! EB Garamond doesn't have a bold weight. This is just a warning. It should silently substitute the regular weight. However, if you need more help, please post a complete minimal example we can compile i.e. start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}`.

Comment: What's an `.lco` is that LyX?

Comment: @cfr is right: there’s no bold (and I think `.lco` has to do with Koma).  But there *is* more than Google offers:  the site dedicated to EB Garamond is http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/, downloads are at https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads, and you should see https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/issues/62 if you want to keep up with development.

Comment: cfr and @Thérèse Thank you both, so the thing is that I'm writing a cover letter, and most of the tutorial that I have seen, they use Adobe Garamond Pro, so I thought that I could search the free alternative, Does anyone of you recommend a font for a cover letter ? Thanks again.

Comment: If you want a Garamond with bold, see https://github.com/rbrito/urw-garamond — but I’ve never used bold in a letter.

Comment: @Thérèse So, that font is good enough if I'm not going to use bold?

Comment: EB Garamond is still a work in progress but already excellent (I have Adobe Premier Pro Opticals, but prefer EB Garamond for some jobs).  Whether it’s appropriate for your letter I can’t say without knowing more about the content, the cultural context, etc.  You could also consider TeX Gyre Pagella.

Comment: Does your letter contain mathematics? If so, I wouldn't use it. But EB Garamond is nice, I think. (I've never used Adobe Garamond Pro.) Unless you are applying for a position in graphic design, the main thing is that people don't notice what font you are using. I use Latin Modern. But I'm sure somebody will tell me that's all wrong.

Comment: I think this is a repeat of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22045/xelatex-error-latex-font-warning-font-shape and probably has the same answer.